# Django Form Template Button

Tags: django

Django accepts and works with form button in format:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

How to make it to work with the following:

```
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you explain what exactly you mean by *"Django accepts and works with form button in format"*? As far as I know the difference in the behaviour of `<input type="submit" .../>` and `<button type="button">...` has nothing to do with Django. Django does not care how a form is submitted from the browser.

This previously posted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-typebutton-and-input-typesubmit) might be of interest.

Comment: When both above examples are places in app, only first one is functional (updates database), second one is not click able, and not functional.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the button to submit the form: ("myform" is the id of your form)

onClick="javascript.document.myform.submit();"