# input type="submit" Vs button tag are they interchangeable?

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c, web-standards, semantic-markup

`input type="submit"` and `button` tag are they interchangeable? or if there is any difference then When to use `input type="submit"` and when `button` ?

And if there is no difference then why we have 2 tags for same purpose?

Comment: Avoid a _funny_ day while using `button` and the `value` attribute in some version of IE, `input` will just send what you expected, some version of IE doesn't play well with `button`s.

Comment: The answers are basically the same as for `input type="button"` vs `button type=button`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use

Comment: This is not "duplicate" for unique question.

Answer (score 183):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

> Buttons created with the BUTTON element function just like buttons created with the INPUT element, but they offer richer rendering possibilities: the BUTTON element may have content. For example, a BUTTON element that contains an image functions like and may resemble an INPUT element whose type is set to "image", but the BUTTON element type allows content.

So for functionality only they're interchangeable!

(Don't forget, `type="submit"` is the default with `button`, so leave it off!)

Comment: Just beware, IE6 submits the values of all buttons on the page, which makes it difficult to determine exactly which button was clicked. Explanation: http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/ie6-and-multiple-button-submit-elements/

Comment: Just FYI you don't _have_ to use `type="submit"` with button, as the default for `type` is `submit`.

Comment: That's what W3C says but I'm pretty sure I've seen cases where `type` default was `button`. I prefer to explicit each attribute to avoid any browser inconsistency.

Comment: According to your ref `type="submit"` seems to be default, so I dont think you need to specify it, right?

Comment: according to reference yes. but not all browsers stick to reference specs,right ?

Comment: This seems like a design flaw. HTML is supposed to be all about "semantics", not "presentation", yet the only difference between `<button>Submit</button>` and `<input type="submit"/>` is literally the presentation.

Comment: @chharvey, no the former may have child nodes; i.e. non-text content. I suppose you could say that aside from brevity is no reason for the latter to exist.

Comment: regarding specifying the `type=submit` of a `button`, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) it says: 

> If you choose to use <button> elements to create the buttons in your form, keep this in mind: if there's only one <button> inside the <form>, that button will be  treated as the "submit" button. So you should be in the habit of expressly specifying which button is the submit button.

Answer (score 81):

The `<input type="button" />` is just a button and won't do anything by itself.
The `<input type="submit" />`, when inside a form element, will submit the form when clicked.

Another useful 'special' button is the `<input type="reset" />` that will clear the form.

Comment: The question is about the button tag not <input type="button">

Comment: The question is about `<input>` and `<button>` tags. You provided useful information about `<input>` in your answer, but it lacks the `<button>` side.

Comment: Ignoring the two comments above, this was actually useful to me.

Answer (score 78):

Although both elements deliver **functionally** the same result *, **I strongly recommend you use `<button>`**:

- Far more explicit and readable.  `input` suggests that the control is *editable*, or can be edited by the user; `button` is far more explicit in terms of the purpose it serves
- Easier to style in CSS; as mentioned above, FIrefox and IE have quirks in which `input[type="submit"]` do not display correctly in some cases
- Predictable requests: IE has verying behaviours when values are submitted in the `POST`/`GET` request to the server
- Markup-friendly; you can nest items, for example, icons, inside the button.
- HTML5, forward-thinking; as developers, it is our responsibility to adopt to the new spec once it is officialized.  HTML5, as of right now, has been official for over one year now, and has been shown in many cases to **boost SEO**.

* <sub>With the exception of `<button type="button">` which by default has no specified behaviour.</sub>

In summary, **I highly discourage use of `<input type="submit"/>`**.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this, especially for the HTML5 semantic point. In 2020, we have to think beyond pure functionality.

Answer (score 51):

**Use <button> tag instead of <input type="button"..>**. It is the advised practice in bootstrap 3.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-tags

> "Cross-browser rendering
>
> As a best practice, we highly recommend using the <button> element
>   whenever possible to ensure matching cross-browser rendering.
>
> Among other things, there's a Firefox bug that prevents us from
>   setting the line-height of <input>-based buttons, causing them to not
>   exactly match the height of other buttons on Firefox."

Comment: +1 for this.  ``button`` is far more explicit, and comes along with ``aria`` accessibility features, and is far easier to style.  It is also forward-thinking, as it is HTML5.

Answer (score 34):

`<input type='submit' />` doesn't support HTML inside of it, since it's a single self-closing tag. `<button>`, on the other hand, supports HTML, images, etc. inside because it's a tag pair: `<button><img src='myimage.gif' /></button>`. `<button>` is also more flexible when it comes to CSS styling.

The disadvantage of `<button>` is that it's not fully supported by older browsers. IE6/7, for example, don't display it correctly.

Unless you have some specific reason, it's probably best to stick to `<input type='submit' />`.

Comment: The answer was from 2 years ago. Also, it's very much possible to specify alternate button text: `<input type="submit" value="Log In" />`

Comment: I'm aware comment was from 2 years ago - that's why giving answers like "Unless you have some specific reason, it's probably best to stick to x" based on the current state of technology should be avoided. But point taken re: specifying alternate button text.

Comment: @nailer You're perfectly entitled to your opinion, but any answer is going to inevitably reference the current state of technology. Maybe HTML 6 will deprecate `<button>` in favour of something new. Does that mean we shouldn't mention a specific tag in answers at all, because it *might* change at some point in the future? I would prefer to leave it as an exercise to the reader to determine how answers apply to their situation. As long as the information is valuable to the reader, I don't see the problem in including it.

Comment: At the time the answer was written, IE6/7 were already out of date. A new web developer reading your post, without checking your supporting arguments and realizing they don't apply anymore, would think there is good reason not to use 'button' elements.

Comment: @nailer There's no universal "out of date" browsers list that is adhered to by everyone. Different workplaces have different requirements for supported browsers. Just because your standard of "supported browsers" in 2011 didn't include IE6/7 doesn't mean that's the case everywhere.

Comment: I'm aware there's no universal "out of date" browsers list - hence not every mentioning such a thing. All I'm saying is that this could be better worded as "IE6/7 don't support display button correctly. If that's a concern, stick to input" I.e., you know browsers will change, account for it. This stops StackOverflow becoming paused forever at IE6 workarounds.

Comment: We can use `html` **with button type submit inside the form** , check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3543649/2218697) , hope helps.

Answer (score 17):

I realize this is an old question but I found this on mozilla.org and think it applies.

> A button can be of three types: submit, reset, or button. A click on a
>   submit button sends the form's data to the web page defined by the
>   action attribute of the  element. 
> A click on a reset button
>   resets all the form widgets to their default value immediately. From a
>   UX point of view, this is considered bad practice. 
> A click on a button
>   button does... nothing! That sounds silly, but it's amazingly useful
>   to build custom buttons with JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form#And_a_<button>_to_finish

Comment: How is it useful if it does nothing?

Comment: Because you can then hook handlers to the click event via Javascript

Comment: @Honey for example you can code a `<button type="button">` to advance a slider/carousel to the next slide.

Answer (score 14):

`<button>` is newer than `<input type="submit">`, is more semantic, easy to stylize and support HTML inside of it.

Answer (score 11):

While the other answers are great and answer the question there is one thing to consider when using `input type="submit"` and `button`. With an `input type="submit"` you [cannot use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587669/825757) a CSS pseudo element on the input but you *can* for a button!

This is one reason to use a `button` element over an input when it comes to styling.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but there is very important (for some cases at least) difference I found: `<input type="submit">` creates key value pair in your request and `<button type="submit">` doesn't. Tested in Chrome and Safari.

So when you have multiple submit buttons in your form and want to know which one was clicked - do not use `button`, use `input type="submit"` instead.

Comment: from my expirience its absolutely other way around, button passes $_POST["submit_name"] and input does NOT. tested on chrome. Firefox sends $_POST["submit_name"] allways.

Comment: @GallAnnonim maybe that depends on document type. Because I definitely use input type=submit and it works on chrome

Comment: intresting... I used <!DOCTYPE html>
using lang "pl" && encoding utf-8 if makes it any diffrence. chrome is 58.0.3029.96

Answer (score -2):

If you are talking about `<input type=button>`, it won't automatically submit the form

if you are talking about the `<button>` tag, that's newer and doesn't automatically submit in all browsers.

Bottom line, if you want the form to submit on click in all browsers, use `<input type="submit">`

Comment: You can use `<button type="submit">` to auto-submit forms.