# javascript page Load occurs on Button Click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My problem is when i clicked on button with id="cmdAddATM" whole .aspx page reload.even though i didnt write any click function associated with it.what is the problem ? becausethis problem is arising some new issues in my project related to ajax/jquery

File Name : AddEditATM.aspx.cs

```
namespace Monitoring_Tool
{
    public partial class AddEditATM : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Generix.fillDropDown(ref litRegion, Generix.getData("dbo.Region", "REGION, Code", "", "", "Code", 1));
        }
    }
}
```

File : AddEditATM.aspx

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        showAddEditATMLoad();
    });
</script>
<body>
// I an not writing full syntax here but i have one button with id "cmdAddATM"
</body>
```

External JS File :

```
function showAddEditATMLoad() { 
    //Its Blank
}
```

My HTML Code:-

```
<table style="margin: 0px auto; width: 90%" runat="server">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th colspan="4" align="center" class="ui-widget-header PageHeader">
              ADD/EDIT ATM
          </th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="vertical-align: bottom; border-style: solid; border-width: thick;">
      <tr>
          <td style="padding-left: 5px" colspan="2">
              Enter ATM ID &nbsp;<input id="txtEditATM" name="txtEditATM" type="text" />
              &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <button id="cmdEditATM">
                  EDIT ATM</button>
          </td>
          <td align="left" style="font-weight: bold" colspan="1">
              OR
          </td>
          <td align="center" colspan="2">
              <button id="cmdAddATM">
                  ADD ATM</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add type attribute to `<button>` tag.

```
<button id="cmdEditATM" type='button'>EDIT ATM</button>
```

SO threads

1. [vs. . Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)
2. [input type=“submit” Vs button tag are they interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable)

Answer (score 2):

If your button is a `<asp:Button runat="server" />` which will render as `<input type="submit" />` on browser. So, It will postback your page.

**Edited** : add `type="button"` attribute with `<button>` tag, 
type attribute for `<button>` tag has three values for it, and default value which  tag is getting in your case is submit, that's why it is submitted your form.

```
1. Submit - For Submitting a Form
2. Reset - For Resetting the Form
3. button - A Simple Button
```

Comment: My Button is Simple...But the Table is runat server

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an `asp:Button` object, you can use the [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29) property or just jQuery to run some client-side code. You could return `false` out of the javascript click event handler (or use jQuery's `event.preventDefault()` method) to stop the postback.

If you never want a postback to occur for this button, just use a normal HTML button (`<input type="button" ... />`). If you need to access this button on the server-side, just add the normal `runat="server"` attribute to it.

Note that an HTML `<input type="submit"/>` button will cause a postback, as it will submit the form on the page.

Answer (score 1):

add `type="button"` attribute to your button. Different browsers may use different default types for the `button` element.

Answer (score 0):

in asp.net any if you add any asp button its automatically convert asp button to submit button so replace asp button with HTML button

```
<input type="button" id='cmdAddATM' value="Button" />
```

Comment: Its not asp button its HTML button only.