# PHP method POST is not working

Tags: php, post, submit

I've got a problem with simple PHP form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" align="center">
    <?php 
        session_start ();
        if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
            echo'<div class="row">';
            echo '<textarea style="resize: none; width: 45%; height: 150px;" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Leave a comment here..."></textarea>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">';
            echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="complete">Submit</button>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<h4>You must be logged in to add comments.</h4>';
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

**And PHP request:**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['complete'])) {
        $text_field = $_POST['comments'];
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `comments` (`text`) VALUES ('$text_field')");
    } 
?>
```

When I click on button nothing happens.

Comment: because your button has type `button` nothing happens, either remove the attribute or change it to `submit`

Comment: If you want to use `type="button"` you'll have to JS to submit the form. Otherwise change it per @Alok's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Change your button type to **submit** instead of **button**. Like this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="complete">Submit</button>
```

**button** type doesn't enforce form to be submitted. If you're required to use **button** type you can handle the form submission on JS by handling onclick event of a button.

Comment: Source?

I think you are wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7117660/4007002

Comment: Only helped because you had `type='button'`   instead of `type='submit'` or nothing.

Comment: I deleted type="button" at all