# Button text has disappeared

Tags: html, css, button, submit

I am trying to create a form with a submit button. I am trying to apply some css to the button in a stylesheet, but for some reason the text has disappeared from the button!
When I remove all css from the stylesheet (or remove the id from the div) the button disappears completely instead of going to the default style. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```css
    #submit 
    {
        background-color: #5AB753;
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 683px;
        top: 500px;
        width: 170px;
        height: 51px;
        font-family: 'Lato';
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        float: left;
    }

    #submit:hover 
    {
        background-color: #96D091;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="submit" type="submit" value="Join now" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `button` element instead of `div`.

Note that the default `type` for a `button` is `submit`, so you can remove that.

```css
#submit {
  background-color: #5AB753;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 683px;
  top: 500px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 51px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: left;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: #96D091;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button id="submit">Join now</button>
```

A Stackoverflow answer with good reasons to use `button` over `input type="submit"` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33663114/5561605

Comment: Of course, it was as easy as that. I shall mark this as an answer asap (can't do it yet because of this time limit)

Answer (score 0):

Current:

```
<div id="submit" type="submit" value="Join now" />
```

Update html code with below code:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Join now" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

use

```css
#submit 
{
    background-color: #5AB753;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 683px;
    top: 500px;
    width: 170px;
    height: 51px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
}

#submit:hover 
{
    background-color: #96D091;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Join now" />
```