# isset condition not working in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements, isset

i was trying to print some text using echo , at first i thought that the error is from the syntax of echo function , then i figured out that the  isset condition is not verified even if i set the button on !!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ajout'])) {
    echo "string";
} else {
    echo "vérifier les champs";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label>id</label>
            <input type="text" name="id">
            <br>
            <label>points</label>
            <input type="text" name="points">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="ajout">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<form method="post">` or change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: your form is likely being submitted as a GET not a POST. if you want POST you have to specify it in the form tag. I suggest you take a basic HTML forms tutorial, if you haven't already.

Comment: flagged as a typo. just add `method='post'`

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale like this? https://hastebin.com/oyumihigak.xml ;)

Comment: good humour lol @IsThisJavascript

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the form's method.

```
<form method="post">
```

According to [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format) the default method is GET.

> method = get|post
>
> This attribute specifies which HTTP method will
>   be used to submit the form data set. Possible (case-insensitive)
>   values are **"get" (the default)** and "post". See the section on form
>   submission for usage information.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

you must use form method for `get` and `post` data into `php`

like  `<form method="post">`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ajout'])) {
    echo "string";
}
else{
    echo "vérifier les champs";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <label>id</label>
            <input type="text" name="id">
            <br>
            <label>points</label>
            <input type="text" name="points">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="ajout">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only `$_POST` variables here would be 'name && 'id', you are checking if a submit button has been set?

You are also missing your form method, which in this case should be "post"

```
<form method="post">
```

edit:

Using `<button type="submit">` instead of `<input type="submit">` is generally more accepted.

> Although both elements deliver **functionally** the same result, **I strongly recommend you use `<button>`**:
>
> - Far more explicit and readable.  `input` suggests that the control is *editable*, or can be edited by the user; `button` is far more explicit in terms of the purpose it serves
> - Easier to style in CSS; as mentioned above, FIrefox and IE have quirks in which `input[type="submit"]` do not display correctly in some cases
> - Predictable requests: IE has verying behaviours when values are submitted in the `POST`/`GET` request to the server
> - Markup-friendly; you can nest items, for example, icons, inside the button.
> - HTML5, forward-thinking; as developers, it is our responsibility to adopt to the new spec once it is officialized.  HTML5, as of right now, has been official for over one year now, and has been shown in many cases to **boost SEO**.
>
> In summary, **I highly discourage use of `<input type="submit" />`**.

Source: [Input Type Submit vs Button Type Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33663114/5283119)

Comment: `Wouldn't it also be <button type="submit"> which then submits the form to the current url if an action has not been set on the form element.` No because `<form>`'s defaults are `method="GET"` and the action is the current page

Comment: He is checking `$_POST` variables which is why I put that as I'm assuming it's posted data he wants.

Comment: haha sorry mate what? :D I'm answering your edit. It doesn't *have* to be a `<button type="submit">`

Comment: sorry pal, misread :) isn't a button preferred due to basic browser functionality? e.g. Hit enter and form submits. I don't remember the last time I actually wrote `<input type="submit">` https://stackoverflow.com/a/33663114/5283119 is a good explanation.

Comment: Yes I'd say it would be preferred but it's not a requirement and doesn't solve the question. I'd suggest editing your answer to make it more clear that a button would be better practice.