# How to change height of <input type = "submit">

Tags: html, css, forms

I am have the following form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search_bar" name="search_bar" value="" placeholder="Zip Code or City">
  <input type="submit" id = "search_bar_submit_button" name="search_bar_submit_button" value="Search">
</form>
```

and the following css:

```
#search_bar, #search_bar_submit_button{
  height: 5em;
}
```

The search bar is now `5em` but the submit button's height has not changed. I have seen answers that suggest using  `<input type="submit" height = "x">`, but feel there has to be a way to do this with CSS?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Should take out that space you have on the button around the id's equal sign though

Comment: Your current code works without any changes. You could maybe check if any other css is overriding the defined css or not.

Comment: As mentioned, your code works as intended. Do a test, try replacing the height with `height: 5em !important;` . See if that works, if it does work, then it means some other class has been set and interfering. Try not to use `!important`. Fix that class that has been interfering.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=submit] {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `<input type='submit'` with `<button type='submit'`.

This will also allow you to apply proper CSS. Please see example below.

```css
input[type='submit'] {
 height: 5em;
}

button[type='submit'] {
 height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<input type='submit' value='Search'/>


<button type='submit'>Search</button>
```

Please go through following link for more details on it.

[input type="submit" Vs button tag are they interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable).

Answer (score 0):

**This may help CSS**

```
#search_bar_submit_button{
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```css
#search_bar_submit_button {
    width: 10em;
    height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search_bar" name="search_bar" value="" placeholder="Zip Code or City"><br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" id = "search_bar_submit_button" name="search_bar_submit_button" value="Search">
</form>
```