# Button type="submit" - unable to change label

Tags: html, reactjs, button, bootstrap-4, form-submit

I have a simple submit button like this:

```
     <button
       type="submit"
       value="Create New Item"
       className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-4"
     />
```

and I've been wondering, why the `value` (label of the button) has the default value instead of desired one (`"Create New Item"`), no matter what I do.
The same goes to `input type="submit"`, but after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable), I decided to stick with `button`.

Any ideas why I can't change the value?

Comment: Seriously, what exactly is the question and the title of the question doesn't make any sense. Why react js tagged in this?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @KarthiKeyan I used `className` instead of `class` in button declaration, which is a React thing. I thought that the fact, that I'm unable to change the label might be a similar case like `class` vs `className`.

Comment: @pidabrow what you see as default value for the label of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<input type="submit" value="Create New Item" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-4" />
```

Change button, to input type="submit"

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
<button onClick={onClickMethod}> Click Here </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

PLease delcare the button as below

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-4">
   Create New Item
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the text inside a button dynamically; you should set it like:

```
<button>{this.state.buttonLabel}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the element like this

```
 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-4">Create 
 New Item</button/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to specify the input type, just replace with as below:

```js
<button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-4">
Create New Item
</button>
```

You can add onClick event.