# Can a input type="submit" button have an HTML label?

Tags: javascript, html

Can you put a tag, to be specific  (ion icons) tag to an input type submit value?

I got these 2 tags and I need to combine them

```
<input type="submit" name="plus" value="" class="btn">
<ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
```

Like so, But to make it work.

```
<input type="submit" name="plus" value="<ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>" class="btn">
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Sure my bad. I am trying to make the Icon as a value of the button.

Comment: You can create a fake input around the input element with a icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with `<input type='submit' ...>`, as HTML labels aren't supported this way. From [`<input type="button">` MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button):

> **Note:** While `<input>` elements of type button are still perfectly valid HTML, the newer `<button>` element is now the favored way to
> create buttons. Given that a `<button>`’s label text is inserted
> between the opening and closing tags, you can include HTML in the
> label, even images.

As such, with the [functionally-same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable) `<button>` you can have HTML labels:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
<button type="submit" name="plus" value="" class="btn btn-primary">
    <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Yes. This is definitely a way to do it. I was really just wondering if it was possible to do with the Input type submit. Thanks.

Comment: @zeddosx I just added a bit more context and sourcing around this - buttons created using `<input>` tags don't support HTML in the label. `<button>`s do support this, and are the modern "preferred" way of creating buttons in web forms.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't know that. Def. going to use this in my future projects.

Answer (score 0):

use button tag

```html
<button name="plus"  class="btn">
  <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline\"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: We could use a little more explanation about why and how the ion-icon tag can be used here when wrapped with the button tag. @coding-warriors can you add more description to help other users with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a fake field, take a look:

```css
.field {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  display: flex;
}

.field__input {
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.field__icon {
  padding-right: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

<div class="field">
    <input class="field__input" type="text">
    <span class="field__icon">
        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
    </span>
</div>
```