# Cannot get axios.put working with backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

hi I have a probleme there. I am coding a crud rest api with (mongo atlas,reactjs,nodejs,express) and want to perform some update data but when using axios.put it is not working.
Also when I use postman with the backend (router.patch ..) it works the problem is I can't get axios.put in frontend working. Here is the axios.put syntax in front end:

```
handleUpdate = async(e) => {
    try{
       const res = await axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/'+e,{
           ville: this.state.ville
       })
       alert(res.data)
       console.log(res.data)
    }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
    }
}
```

and here is the backend part of code of router.patch:
//Update a post {ville}

```
router.patch('/:PostId', async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const updatedPost = await Post.updateOne({_id : req.params.PostId}, 
            { $set: {ville: req.query.ville}
        });
        res.json(updatedPost);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

can U help please ??

Comment: Backend you are using `patch`, and frontend you are using `put`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the PUT method in the backend instead of the PATCH

```
router.put('/:PostId', async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const updatedPost = await Post.updateOne({_id : req.params.PostId}, 
            { $set: {ville: req.query.ville}
        });
        res.json(updatedPost);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

Or, use the PATCH method in the frontend side

```
const res = await axios.patch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/'+e,{
           ville: this.state.ville
       })
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the boths (put,patch) in front end and backend but it does not update maybe that I am wrong with the submit form ? here is my code:

Comment: <label>Saisir l'Id:</label><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" name="user" value={_id}  onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="update" key={_id}  onClick={this.handleUpdate} value={"Update"}/>

Comment: I think you dont need to use input with type="submit". Try to use a button tag for that

Comment: Please find more information about the difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable

Comment: Hi I have tried with button but it seems that it not working, is there a issue with the key={_id}  in the <button key={_id} onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Update</button> or in handleChange itself ?

Comment: Is the handleUpdate function was called when you have clicked on the button?

Comment: to call handleUpdate function I use  onClick to call it inside the button tag

Comment: but do I need to make all the axios.put inside a return instruction inside the (handleUpdate = async(e) => {..} ) function? like (handleUpdate = async(e) => {return(...)}) ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I have asked about handleUpdate function. Are you sure that the function started working when you have clicked on the button? Did you see the result of console.log(res.data) in the console?

Comment: it tell me on the console :PUT http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (vendors~main.chunk.js:872)
    at settle (vendors~main.chunk.js:1106)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (vendors~main.chunk.js:346)

Comment: Have you changed the PATCH to the PUT on the backend side?

Comment: Also as you can see [object%20Object] is not correct id

Comment: add the console.log(e) into the handleUpdate function before the axios call and check what is it.

Comment: yes boths are put. in mongo atlas the default index is an object type but I think that it don't understand the object format of id.

Comment: SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: MouseEvent, target: button, …} this is the result of console

Comment: So what are you see by console.log(e)?

Comment: it gives me : SyntheticBaseEve(nt {_reactName: "onClick", _targetInst: null, type: "click", nativeEvent: MouseEvent, target: button, …} ) before ​ (PUT http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)) error so before the axios.put

Comment: You can't send the object as a path parameter. It should be number of sting

Comment: do I need to convert the object to string ? but in front end or back end ?

Comment: the "e" which you are sending as a path parameter should be string or number

Comment: for example, your full request URL should be like 127.0.0.1:3000/posts/111231312312313123

Comment: when I want to modify the default index in mongo atlas to string it won't want to  modify

Comment: do I need to add a new column of string witch is iduser ? after the _id default index ?

Comment: Ah, man. It's not related to modifying the record in MongoDB. From the backend, you have received a 404 because the URL is wrong. You are sending the wrong parameters to the backend. The URL should be 127.0.0.1:3000/posts/111231312312313123 instead of 127.0.0.1:3000/posts/[object%20Object]

Comment: I have changed  the  axios.put url to the url+id like this  axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/60b758fcadd9641d4425a4e4'

Comment: but it works on postman but in axios dont work

Comment: I sure that what I am sending is the param of id but  how to make it the right url ?

Comment: Ok. Then add a console.log("TEST", req.params.PostId, req.query.ville) to the backend  before calling the database update function.
And also try to use ObjectId(req.params.PostId) on the backend when you try to update an item. ObjectId is from mongodb

Comment: Like 
const updatedPost = await Post.updateOne({_id : ObjectId (req.params.PostId)}, 
            { $set: {ville: req.query.ville}
        });

Comment: I have changed the  { $set: {ville: req.query.ville} to { $set: {ville: req.body.ville} and it works with the id in url by default

Comment: but it won't work when I pass the id from parameter in function

Comment: It's because you are sending [object%20Object] as a path parameter instead of Id

Comment: You need to add the console loges and see what's happened

Comment: it gives me [object Undefined] which is the id. Do I need to convert to toString ?

Comment: no. It should not look like [object Undefined]. It should look like 121412412412

Answer (score 2):

Hi thank you CyberEternal for your help and support, I have found the issue and the problem is solved.
after changing both the backend and front end to put, I have released that in back end I need to write $set: {ville: req.body.ville} unstead of $set: {ville: req.query.ville} here is the new code in backend:
//Update a post {ville}

```
router.put('/:PostId', async (req,res) => {
    try{
        const updatedPost = await Post.updateOne({_id : req.params.PostId}, 
            { $set: {ville: req.body.ville}
        });
        res.json(updatedPost);
    }catch(err){
        res.json({message: err});
    }
});
```

and here is the code in front end (I have also add a prompt so the user can enter the id in string format and added the id to the url):

```
handleUpdate = async(e) => {
    try{
        var person = prompt("Veuillez saisir l'Id de l'employé");
       const res = await axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts/'+person,{
           ville: this.state.ville
       })
       alert(res.data)
       console.log(res.data)
    }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
    }
}
```

It Works !! Thanks !