# Symfony6 input submission and routing for GET from twig template

Tags: twig, form-submit, symfony6

I am working in Symfony6 getting info from a readonly endpoint. I am rewriting an existing but severely deprecated app, so I know exactly how the stuff needs to go together to update what is retrieved. Also I am not using Symfony forms as this is massively simple and nothing is getting stored or anything like that. My homepage is doing just fine hitting '/', and if I copy and paste all of the '?foo=bar&date=2023-11-16' to the end it pulls it up with the correct stuff in the correct places as expected. However I can't seem to figure out how to get the info from the template into the thing and updating the view.

```
<div>
    <form class="class" role="form" action="this-is-the-question-i-think" method="get">
        <label for="foo" class="form-label">Foo</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ bar }}">
        <label for="date" class="form-label">Date:</label>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="theDate" value="{{ dateVariable }}">
        <button type="submit">Update View</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have tried action = "{{ path(path) }}" which fills in the route name 'app_default_homepage' which loads the homepage without the default values and not the input. I have tried action = "{{ relative_path('/?foo=bar&date=2023-11-16') }}" which loads the '/?' but default values (hardwiring what's added thinking if I can even get it to load the page with the values added to the url, I can then maybe tackle a twig extension to create the string for the url from the input values. I don't know if I need to change to adding an onsubmit to the button instead of using an action to update the variable values in a controller and then redirecting to whatever string I create, but some of my fumblings have thrown the error that "Unable to get URL for named route '/?foo=bar&date=2023-11-16'" or similar, and I'm running out of spaghetti to throw at the wall or new wordings to search.

Editing to add controller code as requested:

```
#[Route('/', name: 'app_default_homepage')]
public function homepage(Request $request)
{
    $stats = null;
// this baseInit sets the date formatting, region is null on the homepage at first load, the after the ? has region=stuff that sets to entire repo
    $this->baseInit($request);

    if ($this->region == null) {
        $entireRepository = new Region("1", "Repository", "Entire Repository");
        $this->region = $entireRepository->getDisplayId();
// retrieveStatsForEntireRepository sets the $this->region and then passes to same retrieveStats as in the else below
        $stats = $this->statsService->retrieveStatsForEntireRepository(
            $this->fromDate,
            $this->toDate
        );
    } else {
        $stats = $this->statsService->retrieveStats(
            $this->region,
            $this->fromDate,
            $this->toDate
        );
    }
    return $this->render('homepage.html.twig', [
        'stats' => $stats,
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: attach the controller code, you need to check if form is submitted.

Comment: I added controller code to the original question. Unfortunately the current working version I'm trying to recreate is so deprecated that I can't run it locally to follow the steps through that way. I'm not sure how to check if form is submitted since I'm not using Symfony Forms, but I'll poke at that question now. (for further background I'm originally a js developer, so there's some second language struggles too)

Answer (score -1):

After figuring out this was not actually submitting the form, I set the action back to {{ path(path) }} in the twig template, took it all the way back to w3schools php form handling page, and changed my `<button>` to an `<input type="submit"...`

I'm assuming the change to input instead of button is the part that fixed this specific issue. On to the next one.

Comment: There is no difference between `<input type="submit" ...` or `<button type="submit" ...` - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117639/input-type-submit-vs-button-tag-are-they-interchangeable). So changing this wouldn't have affected anything