# Should I use HTML <button> or <input>?

Tags: html, form-submit

I want to create a form-submit button on an HTML form which has different text than the keyword which will be submitted to the host.  So I used

```
<button type="submit" name="SubmitAction" value="Done" accesskey="D"><u>D</u>one for Now</button>
```

But [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) warns:

> Note: If you use the `<button>` element in an HTML form, different browsers may submit different values. **Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form**.

Is there any way to create a button using `<input>` the text showing on the button different from the value that will be submitted to the host?

What are the variations that different browser send with a `<button>`?

Note: I do not have to support anything older that IE 9 and the use will actually be with current versions of Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between <input type='submit' /> and <button type=submit>text</button>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-button)

Comment: You could use an onsubmit function to append the value you want to the form when the input is pressed like explosion pills says.

Comment: You appear to be quoting http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp — Please don't confuse W3Schools with the W3C. The W3C maintain a number of web standards. W3Schools bask in the reflected glory of having a similar name while hosting some (mostly out of date) tutorials, many of which have errors and security problems.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but here are other html 5 input types that are supported by different browsers in case you are interested: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/

Comment: @Quentin: I didn't realize that - thanks.  I have not been able to find an HTML5 and CSS3 reference on w3c.com to use.  The standards abstracts are not helpful for use as a reference.

Comment: The only browser i've noticed having a problem with `<button>` is IE7.  That's enough to make it a problem, but one can write some JS to make `<button>` elements act correctly.

Comment: @cHao: Does IE7 have issues? I know IE6 does (submitting the innerHTML of the button). What's IE7's situation?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Probably the same as IE6's.  It submits the innerHTML of the button as the value, even if there's a `value` attribute on the button.  The `value` property, and even `getAttribute('value')`, returns the button's HTML.  You have to get `attributes.value.value` or something like that in order to even see the real value attribute.

Comment: @cHao: I could be wrong but I think it's just IE6.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: I wish it were just IE6.  Would have made a recent project of mine a bit simpler.  :)  What's more, IE7 seems to submit the content of every `<button type="button">` in the form, even ones that were never clicked or anything.  Seems to be fixed only since IE8.

Comment: Thankfully, I don't have to support anything other that current browsers for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<button>` vs. `<input>` difference is pretty antiquated, and you should have no problem getting away with using either one in modern browsers.

If you want to use `<input type="submit">` to submit a value other than what is displayed ... don't.  Instead, just add another input element:

```
<input type="submit" value="Displayed Value">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="Actual Value">
```

Comment: About the multiple `input` idea: But I have multiple buttons, each submitting a different action - Save, Done, Publish, Discard.

Comment: just append the hidden input when the form is submitted depending on which button is pressed with some javascript on the onsubmit event

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey you can rely on the submit button's name, but not its value

Comment: @ExplosionPills yeah i always use the name attribute to see what button got pressed

Comment: @Nathan: I really hate using JS for critical functionality (as opposed to augmentation) - It would be simpler to map different submit names to a singular SubmitAction on the host.  But thanks for the idea.