# How to get the page title into a input's value?

Tags: php

I want my hidden `input` field to get the page `title` as its `value`.

This is my `testmail.php` code.

```
    <p>From: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></p>
<p>Subject: <?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?></p>
<p>Email: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?></p>
<p>Phone Number: <?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?></p>
<p style="width:300px;">Message: <?php echo $_POST['message']; ?></p>
```

and this is my form code

```
                <form action="testmail.php" method="post" class="cf">

                    <label for="name">* Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">

                        <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="<?php value $_POST['pagetitle']; ?>">

                    <label for="email">* Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid Email Address">

                    <label for="phone"> Phone:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter areacode and number">

                    <label for="message">* Message:</label>
                        <textarea name="message"></textarea>

                        <button type="input">Send</button>
            </form>
```

Is there a way to get the title automatically?

Comment: How is your page title set in the first place? Also, this is a weird question.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know how to explain this question fully. My page title is set in the html. I wanted to know if I could get the page title automatically so I could know from what page the form was sent? Hope you understand my question.

Comment: If your page is generated by PHP, can't you put the title in a variable and echo it in the hidden input's value? Or is it a JavaScript question?

Comment: Yeah I could put the title in a variable but then if I use the form in multiple pages I have to change the title on each page right?

Comment: I agree with @Sébastien and also, other than that, you know that the requeseting page is always available. Look at the `$_SERVER` variable. Specifically I think `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. That will give you the page filename.

Comment: andresr, that's the thing about a variable. It can be whatever you want it to be. Wouldn't you want to change the page title on each page???

Comment: @ButtleButkus Yes that's true I'll go with that. I'm going to have to change my html page into php for that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pure javascript way using the onsubmit event.

```
<form onsubmit="this.subject.value=document.title;">
    <input type="text" name="subject" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

To give you a better understanding of the `onsubmit` event as the name suggests it executes the contained javascript when the user submits the form. The operation `this.subject.value=document.title` working from right to left basically says assign the value of `document.title` to the `value` attribute of the element with the `name` of `subject` in `this` specific form.

Using your existing form it should look like this (I added the onsubmit event and fixed up errors in your html as well as added the appropriate id's to form elements):

```
<form action="testmail.php" method="post" class="cf" onsubmit="this.subject.value=document.title;">

    <label for="name">* Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />

    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="" />

    <label for="email">* Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter a valid Email Address" />

    <label for="phone"> Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter areacode and number" />

    <label for="message">* Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Yes this worked quick without having to change my html to php. Would this work if a form is created in a php file?

Comment: Yeah it'll work anywhere since php outputs html. The browser doesn't care where it came from so long as the information is correct when the browser sees it. I also fixed up your html and gave your form elements the proper id to use in conjunction with the `label for` attribute

Comment: Remember the `for="someid"` needs to match an `id="someid"` on some form element.

Comment: yes correct forgot to set my `id`. Do I have to change the `button` to an `input` ?

Comment: @andresr I had made changes the same time you submitted the edit so I couldn't accept it but made the change manually. Sorry about that!

Comment: Also I'd recommend using <input type="submit"> read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-button) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This will set the value of your hidden `input` field once the page has finished loading.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('input[name="subject"]').val($('title').text());
});    
</script>
```

Comment: I like this jquery function too. Might be using it for some forms. Thanks r-sal!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to do so, assuming you're using jQuery, bind `submit` event to your form

```
$('your_form_selector').on('submit', function(){
    $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
            .attr('name', 'title')
            .attr('value', document.title)
            .appendTo($(this));
});
```