# define input as submit in symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

How I can set button type as input tag in symfony2?

```
<input type="submit" id="id_submit" name="click to go next" class="submit"></input>
```

using symfony2 formType as 
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

```
    $builder

    ->add('submit', 'button',array('attr' => array('class'=>'submit','type'=>'input')))
    ;
}
```

As it shows

```
<button type="submit" id="ponemonSurvey_submit" name="click here to go" class="submit"></input>
```

Comment: I want this behavior

    <input type="submit" id="id_submit" name="click to go next" class="submit"></input>

rathen than 

    <button type="submit" id="ponemonSurvey_submit" name="click here to go" class="submit"></input>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add button to your forms, you can use the inputType `submit`  (symfony2.3 and more)
[Documentation](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html)

```
$builder->add('save', 'submit', array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'submit'),
    'label' => "click to go next"
));
```

You have also the `reset` and `button` inputType.

`button` html tag is more recommended than `input` tag, it's more flexible (you can use an image as a button for example).

If you really want a `<input type="submit"` rather than `<button type="submit"`, you can add your own inputType to symfony as descripted there in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)

Comment: I want this behavior

    <input type="submit" id="id_submit" name="click to go next" class="submit"></input>

rathen than 

    <button type="submit" id="ponemonSurvey_submit" name="click here to go" class="submit"></input>

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your tag also showing me

<button> tag in html, not <input> tag

Comment: Check my link to see the difference between the two of them.  The button tag is more recommended than the input one, button is more flexible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-button

Comment: You are correct, but still I need to define input tag as submit in formtype. I dont want to show button tag as submit.

Comment: Kindly help me if you know how I can define <input type="submit"> in my formType.

Answer (score 1):

From Symfony 2.3 and so on (doesn't work on earlier versions):

```
$builder->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Click to go next',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'the_class_you_want',
                )));
```

The Submit button has an additional method isClicked() that lets you check whether this button was used to submit the form. This is especially useful when a form has multiple submit buttons:

```
if ($form->get('save')->isClicked()) {
    // ...
}
```

**Tip**: you shouldn't put "click to go next" in the `name` attribute. This attribute is not aimed to receive human readable text. Use the `'label'` option instead, like I wrote above.

**Note**: you can't change the css `id` attribute of an input in the FormBuilder. To do that, you have to use the template.

Comment: I want this behavior

    <input type="submit" id="id_submit" name="click to go next" class="submit"></input>

rathen than 

    <button type="submit" id="ponemonSurvey_submit" name="click here to go" class="submit"></input>

Comment: See my edit. The first code area indicates what you want to do. And you can't change an id attribute in the FormBuilder (see last note in my answer).

Comment: Kindly help me if you know how I can define <input type="submit"> in my formType.

Comment: @AliHassan well this is just what I did, dude... If you can't read it's not my fault.