# Error in link a sign up form with my database using PHP

Tags: php

Hello guys good morning .

I have an issue , I.m trying to link my Sign up form to my database using PHP , so when someone fill the form all the data should go the database , But the problem is that it's not working , the code pass everything and he go to the ELSE sentence , please let me know what i did wrong and if there is a solve for it explain it so i learn from it .

The code fun the last false sentence .

PHP code :

```
$hostname="*************"; 
$username="*************";  
$password="*************";       
$database="*************"; 

$connect=mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
if(!$connect)
    {
        die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db($database);

if(isset($_REQUEST['Submit']))
    {
     $username  =   ($_REQUEST['username']); // SANITIZE INPUTS !
     $firstname =   ($_REQUEST['firstname']);
     $pincode   =   ($_REQUEST['pincode']);
     $lastname  =   ($_REQUEST['lastname']);
     $email     =   ($_REQUEST['email']);
     $password  =   ($_REQUEST['password']);
     $website   =   ($_REQUEST['website']);
     $phonenumber   =   ($_REQUEST['phonenumber']);
     $zipcode   =   ($_REQUEST['zipcode']);
     $address1  =   ($_REQUEST['address1']);
     $address2  =   ($_REQUEST['address2']);
     $company   =   ($_REQUEST['company']);
     $sq    =   ($_REQUEST['sq']);
     $country   =   ($_REQUEST['Country']);
     $city  =   ($_REQUEST['city']);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO customers 
            VALUES (0,'$pincode','$username','$firstname','$lastname',
                   '$email','$password', '$sq', '$company', '$website', 
                   '$address1', '$address2', '$city','$zipcode',
                   '$country')";                
    $res=mysql_query($sql);
    if($res)
        {
            echo "Sumbimted";
        }   
    else 
        {
            echo "Something went wrong ";
        }

    }

else 
    {
        echo "false";
    }


?>
```

My form page Code :

```
 <form role="form" class="signup" action="SignUpPHP.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Username</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter a username" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Pin Code</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pincode" name="pincode" placeholder="Pin Code from 4 Digite" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FirstName" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" required>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Phone Number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Your Phone Number" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="inputSuccess">Country</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
              <select class="form-control m-bot15" value="" name="country" required>
                    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                    <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
                    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
                    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
                    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
                    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
                    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
                    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
                    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
                    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
                    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
                    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
                    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
                    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
                    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
                    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
                    <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
                    <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
                    <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
                    <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
                    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                    <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                    <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
                    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
                    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
                    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
                    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
                    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
                    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
                    <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
                    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
                    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
                    <option value="CN">China</option>
                    <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
                    <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
                    <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
                    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
                    <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
                    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
                    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
                    <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
                    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
                    <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
                    <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
                    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
                    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
                    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
                    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
                    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
                    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
                    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
                    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
                    <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
                    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
                    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
                    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
                    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
                    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
                    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                    <option value="FR">France</option>
                    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
                    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
                    <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
                    <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
                    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
                    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
                    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
                    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
                    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
                    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
                    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
                    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
                    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
                    <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
                    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
                    <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
                    <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
                    <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
                    <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
                    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
                    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
                    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
                    <option value="IN">India</option>
                    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
                    <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
                    <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
                    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                    <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
                    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
                    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
                    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                    <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
                    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
                    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
                    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
                    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
                    <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
                    <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
                    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
                    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                    <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
                    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
                    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
                    <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
                    <option value="LY">Libya</option>
                    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
                    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
                    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                    <option value="MO">Macao</option>
                    <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
                    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
                    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
                    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
                    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
                    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
                    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
                    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
                    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
                    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
                    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
                    <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
                    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                    <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                    <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                    <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
                    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
                    <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
                    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
                    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
                    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
                    <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
                    <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
                    <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
                    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
                    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
                    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
                    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
                    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
                    <option value="NU">Niue</option>
                    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
                    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
                    <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
                    <option value="PW">Palau</option>
                    <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
                    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
                    <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
                    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
                    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
                    <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
                    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
                    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
                    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
                    <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
                    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
                    <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
                    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
                    <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
                    <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
                    <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                    <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
                    <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
                    <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                    <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                    <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
                    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
                    <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
                    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
                    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
                    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
                    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
                    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                    <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
                    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
                    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
                    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
                    <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
                    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
                    <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                    <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
                    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
                    <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
                    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
                    <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
                    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                    <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                    <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
                    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
                    <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
                    <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
                    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
                    <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
                    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
                    <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
                    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
                    <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
                    <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
                    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
                    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
                    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
                    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                    <option value="US">United States</option>
                    <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
                    <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
                    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
                    <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
                    <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
                    <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                    <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                    <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
                    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
                    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
                    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
              </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">City</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Your City" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Zip Code</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Enter Your Zip Code" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Address (1) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address1" name="address1" placeholder="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Address (2) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" name="address2" placeholder="Optional">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Security Question :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sq" name="sq" placeholder="" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Website :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" name="website" placeholder="Optional">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="FirstName">Company :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Optional">
        </div>

          <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" required> Agree on our <a href="https://newtecplanet.com/terms.html">Terms</a>
              </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: are you sure you made a good connection to the database?

Comment: try `<input type='submit' name='submit'>`, if it works then check your button tag

Comment: i tried it gave me the same thing  "false "

Comment: @Porg-Laith SJ for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-butto

Comment: I tried but same thing . " False "

Comment: I tried your code but its working for me, I had just made one change `Country` to `country` in signupphp page

Comment: i refreshed the page and it gave me " Something went wrong  " it now the problem in inserting the data in the database , but still need help in this too if thats ok .

Comment: You should try error handler to see what is wrong on your PHP code. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: damn i still can't figure it out , i did just like you and still not working .

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for the advice , i will work on that .

Comment: insert query format `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);` only if you have missed any column yoh will come to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming it is showing the 
>   `Something went wrong` message

You are not testing for errors in your query processing properly.

If you show the error generated by the database it will assist you in solving the issue rather than just a `echo "Something went wrong ";`

So change this section:

```
    if($res === false) {
        echo 'Query failed ' . mysql_error();
        echo "\n$sql\n";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Submited";
    }
```

> Oh and like I said above:
>
> Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
>   is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
>   Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

I am guessing here, but I would guess that you dont need the first param in the VALUES Clause i.e. `VALUES (0,` because I assume that is a `auto-increment` column, so always using 0 will cause an error.

If thats the case do not add that parameter i.e.

```
VALUES ('$pincode','$username','$firstname','$lastname',
       '$email','$password', '$sq', '$company', '$website', 
       '$address1', '$address2', '$city','$zipcode',
       '$country')";
```

Or pass NULL

```
VALUES (NULL,'$pincode','$username','$firstname','$lastname',
       '$email','$password', '$sq', '$company', '$website', 
       '$address1', '$address2', '$city','$zipcode',
       '$country')";
```

Its simpler just to leave it off completely

#### Alternativley

you may have got the parameters in the wrong order i.e. not matching the order the database has them defined. In which case it is probably failing because a datatype does not match OR the data passed is to large for the column it is being placed into.

Its always safest to use the form

```
INSERT INTO Table (column1, column2) VALUES ('data1', 'data2' )
```

To make sure values go into the correct column. Remember its always possible to change a column in the database, add/remove and affect the default order of columns, then all statements like this will fail and you have to go searching through your code to find odd errors that are occuring. Remember it may not be you that amends the table layout.

#### Column order is wrong

You are not collecting the C_securityanswer from the user on the screen. So you are not passsing that to the query! Therefore the section above I called **Alternatively** will take effect and all the following columns are 1 adrift. This does not actually cause an issue (datatype or column size wize) until we get to trying to place TEXT $country into the column C_zipcode which is an int(10) where it will all go to bad in a hurry.

Actually that field should probably not be an int but thats whats causing the query to fail.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers 
        VALUES (0,'$pincode','$username','$firstname','$lastname',
               '$email','$password', '$sq', 
               ??? there is a column here on the database
               '$company', '$website', 
               '$address1', '$address2', '$city','$zipcode',
               '$country')";
```

However the real reason for your current error is you have removed this line

```
$res=mysql_query($sql);
```

So the query never actually gets run!!!! Woops

Comment: Ok so i added what you told me to check whats the error and this is whats it should me know : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /homepages/1/d609226644/htdocs/php/SignUpPHP.php on line 46

Comment: Opps TYPO Alert: Missed the `{` from the IF line: Fixed it now

Comment: Ok my bad i forgot that in the new code there is to else in the first IF , so i deleted the one that print " something went wrong " and now it printed submited . i will check the database to see the data

Comment: Did you remove the `0` from the first param in the VALUE list?

Comment: yes i did , i check the database now and it gave me this " MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0003 sec)" so nothing has been submitted , thats weird .

Comment: Better check the IF code is like I have it and it has not messed with the rest of the code when you pasted it in

Comment: I'm confused , everything is right but the data not getting in lol

Comment: See additional info. Now its your turn have made a TYPO

Comment: lol another door ( error ) :  Query failed Query was empty INSERT INTO customers VALUES ('2014','Laith ','Laith ','SJ ','laythalhaj@yahoo.com','kk;lkjl;kj;klj', 'laith',' asdasdasdsad', 'asdasdasd', 'asdasdasd', 'Abd Alkareem Hamdan', 'Abd Alkareem Hamdan', 'Al Zarqa','11671','AL')

Comment: See the other portion of my added answer **Alternatively** and **Column Order Wrong**

Comment: I have changed the datatype and tried again and fixed the columns but still getting the same error :/ , Kill me , just kill me lol

Comment: No!!! Add the column list before the value list `INSERT INTO Table (column1, column2) VALUES ('data1', 'data2' )` then it can never be wrong

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO customers ('C_pincode','C_username','C_firstname','C_lastname','C_email','C_password','C_securityquestion','C_securityanswer','C_companyname','C_websitename','C_address1','C_address2','C_city','C_zipcode','C_country') VALUES ('$pincode','$username','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$password', '$sq',' $sa', '$company', '$website', '$address1', '$address2', '$city','$zipcode','$country')";

Comment: Ok well as i said you need to kill me lol i forgot that when you type the columns that you want to add the values in should be like this , just like what you typed : insert into customers (column1,column2) values ('data1','data2)  not ('column1','column2') lol it worked now ,thank you man , your code was working really fine but it was stupid mistake from me lol thank you again thank you so much .

Comment: The column names must be in the same order as the data variables

Comment: They really are at the same order

Comment: `What's Your mother....` has a single quote in it. you have to `mysql_read_escape_string()` all your variables. **Its now I have to say using PDO would be a better solution with parameterised queries. Sorrry**

Comment: oK let me try to use that , i will get back to you