# Form sends GET instead of POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post, apache2

I have searched the all questions with similar title, no solution for me yet.

I have a website running on apache2. I need to submit sensitive information through a form and I need to use POST method. Instead of POST, it sends GET request.

HTML:

```
<form action="/add_user.php" method='POST'>
   Enter Username: <input type="email" name="email" required="required" /> <br/>
   Enter password: <input type="password" name="password" required="required" /> <br/>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$email=$_POST['email']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];
//do stuff
?>
```

I have opened Network monitor in Firefox, and the method is confirmed as GET. I have tried to even make it PUT instead of POST, still it sends GET. Also, `$email` and `$password` get the values if I change them to `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a general note, but you're mixing double and single quotes. Could cause unpredictable things like that to happen

Comment: It was both double quoted, and both single quoted, neither didn't work. Just at my last try I tried to mix them to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Are you submitting form via AJAX?

Comment: Any javascript on form submit?

Comment: Try using lowercase "post"

Comment: @u_mulder Nope, no js on whole page.

Comment: @scaisEdge Tried, no success.

Comment: This is quite strange, could you upload your code on a server to let us try it in live ?

Comment: @zakhefron I am submitting it just the way like it is presented in code. Plain HTML/PHP relation.

Comment: Maybe your problem is with input type submit. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3543695/5885018

Comment: Just check what happens when adding  enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form. Also check by changing post to get

Comment: @statosdotcom Thanks for the hint to check submit, never thought it could be problem in it. I googled submit button for POST method and got this: <button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="add_user.php">Submit</button> 

It finally works now.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — https://www.evernote.com/l/AAPXC994GgVNFKtPk7YDSTJH9Vfscf0SRpY — whatever it is, it isn't expressed by the code in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to solve this is to reinforce your intentions by expliciting `formmethod="post"`, like this:

```
<button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="add_user.php">Submit</button>
```

EDIT: for those who are learning HTML and interested in help each other here in SO (thus not having time to cry), here you can find why is `formmethod` a truly and valid, prototyped and specified, overriding method: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#attr-fs-formmethod

Comment: I don't know why this got all the upvotes. This is a force, not a solution. It's the equivalent of writing `Important!` at the end of a CSS rule. Better to solve the problem instead.

Comment: What would be another anwser then? The following is not applicable in our case

Answer (score 5):

If like me you gone from Routed url (like in Laravel) to plain PHP, and wonder why the file `/user/store/index.php` responds that it receives a GET request using:

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/store">
  <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" />
  <button type="submit">Create a new user</button>
</form>
```

Just check it again... Yes you forgot a trailing slash... so `/user/store` will receives only get, while `/user/store/` will receive what you form requested.

**Edit**

I inspected what Laravel does, and it solves this particular issue with this addition in their .htaccess ([check the original file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess#L12-L15)).

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I was going crazy. Thank you. Why do forms work this way??

Comment: Apparently, taking from another Stackoverflow answer, this is because the way the default php server (php - S) and Appache work: if you ask for `/user/store`, it tried to get the file with this name, but this is not a php file but a folder. Howether, you fix this issue by adding a trailing slash, which by default will try to find the `index.php` in the folder, so it works well and responds to your router. Apparently, we could be able to tweak the .htaccess file to tell Appache to always add a trailing slash, but 1. This might not be always wanted 2. I do not know how to do it with php - S...

Comment: @M.I.Wright I just added something that might help you if you use Appache as a server. I think php built-in server will not react to this file however.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, though, that doesn't apply to me -- I was using Python/Flask when I experienced this issue. I'd defined the route without the trailing slash, too, so there was no redirect or anything, which made the GET-not-POST behavior really surprising to me