# Recieving "GET" instead of "POST"

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm doing a project and using PHP. There is signup.php page with form and it is sending "GET" instead of "POST". Even after hours of debugging, I could not come up with anything, I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908024/form-sends-get-instead-of-post) but that seems to be of no help in my case. I have similar login.php page with almost same code and that works fine, I don't know what wrong I'm doing.

```
<form name="signUpForm" id="signUpForm" action="signup.php" method="post">
    //form elements
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Following the question mentioned, I tried to change it to

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" formmethod="POST" formaction="signup.php" >Submit</button>
```

But this also gives the same result.

```
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
```

Above statement prints "GET" in PHP.

I would like to know what I'm missing, I know similar questions exist but I checked them before putting the question.

Comment: `<input type="submit"`

Comment: @nogad nothing changed, I already tried it, anyways Thank you

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` is that populated? are you dong any server side redirecting?

Comment: @nogad it says "array(0) { }"..redirecting only after successful insertion in database..but it is sending "GET" so I'm not able to read data to process

Comment: last guess .. no other form on the page? is the url public?

Comment: @nogad Public?as is?..I did'nt get you..form is submitting to itself you can have a look https://ideone.com/f93owG  .. I have a similar login page https://ideone.com/w7feHQ which works just fine

Comment: the post works, the form then is redirected using your header call, on both success or **error**. you can see this with: `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { exit('post');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133223/discussion-between-100rabh-and-nogad).

Answer (score 0):

GET is the automatic default. Make sure that you close all of your open form tags and set the method="POST".
I just ran into this problem!