# PHP form using Post. Error: Undefined array key. However it works when I use get. (w3schools example)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I am trying to make a form on my website where users can submit their name and their score will get saved to a list of highscores. (its a quiz game.)

I tried learning to use forms using w3schools. I used this example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

with welcome.php looking like this:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I literally copy and pasted this example and tried running it and i get this error message:

```
WelcomeWarning: Undefined array key "name" in [filelocation] on line 4

Your email address is:Warning: Undefined array key "email" in [filelocation] on line 5
```

However when I replaced all the "post" with "get" it worked. Why? What do I need to do to get it to work with post?

EDIT: Also I left the "post" in the html but i replaced the POST in the welcome.php with REQUEST. It now works, however I think its somehow using GET instead of POSTs because i can see the input in the URL. I definitely need to avoid this.
Maybe this helps

Thank you!

Comment: Warning! You are open to XSS attacks. Use proper escaping and `<script>alert('foo')</script>` in the form fields will not do any harm.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` combines `$_GET` and `$_POST` but might get unpredictable if the sames keys appear in both. If you did not edit your question than `$_POST` would have been populated. To test this put a `<?php print_r($_POST);` at the top of the `welcome.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might running directly welcome.php page.

Replace your welcome.php with

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { ?>
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
    <?php }
          else{ ?>
     <script> location.replace("yourHtmlFileName.html") </script>
     <?php     } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried doing this and it simply reloads my HTML website when i click submit

Comment: `Form Method: <?= $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]?> </br>` add this in welcome.php page, after body start to determine your form method is post or get. If you writing post and there you see get, it might problem with your browser.

Comment: I tried it and it says get! which is so weird! It happened in both my browsers though.

Comment: Thank you so much! Knowing this was my problem i finally figured it out. I started googling more specifically and found this question with the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908024/form-sends-get-instead-of-post

Answer (score 1):

The W3Schools page you linked has **two examples using both POST and GET on the same page.**

Considering you said you didn't edit the code, i think it's very likely you copied the HTML code of the **second example that uses GET** whiile using the PHP code from the **first example that uses POST.** The code block is right below is.

Frankly, this kind of thing happens to everyone sometimes, make sure you're properly hydrated and carry on!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your concern. I just double checked and I used the correct code snippets. When I use the GET snippets it works but when I copy the POST code it does not. Have you tried running it?

Comment: @cactus i just tried it on the W3Schools link you included, works fine on there. I can't tell you much except that there's nothing wrong with the code you posted. It would give you the warnings if you open that PHP page **without** submitting the form first, but it sounds like that's not the case..

Comment: When I try it on W3Schools it works to but when i try it on my php server it does not. I figured out in the meantime, that the welcome.php is receiving a GET method, even though i specified post in the html. Maybe something is wrong with my server.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Once I realized I was gettin a GET instead of a POST I googled more specifically and found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908024/form-sends-get-instead-of-post Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Another issue which I faced for similar problem was that I have named my html file as "index.html" and also php file as "index.php" because of which php was working on php files first In my case changing the name of file worked out for me

Comment: changing the name of php file because of which html filed served first and then action get served on html

Answer (score 0):

try this php code in your index page:

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

echo $name .'Welcome '. $lastname .'your email adress is: '. $email;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you literally copied and pasted a example from w3schools and got those errors, **check if you're using an VSCode with live server plugin**. I just stop using the live server plugin (Five server) and my problem with PHP was gone. For some reason, that plugin was the origin of **ERROR: Undefined array key**.

Comment: If there is an PHP array error it means that PHP was executed and therefor a full webserver was used and not the live server. But it is worthwhile to lookout for any `<?php..` appearing in the browser window. If that is the case than yes, a `live server` not a web server was used.

Comment: I think the answer is unclear and not related to the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>QUALITY</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif:wght@800&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <?php include './connect.php'; ?>

    <?php
    $fullName = $_POST['contact_name'];
    $email = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $companyName = $_POST['contact_company'];

    $login_form = $conn->prepare("insert into contact_info(contact_name, contact_email, contact_company) values(?, ?, ?)");
    $login_form->bind_param("sss", $fullName, $email, $companyName);
    $execval = $login_form->execute();
    $login_form->close();
    ?>

    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="border-bottom pb-3 pt-2">
                <img class="header-image" src="../images/Maxbyte.jpg" alt="Maxbyte">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="h-100vh bg-light">
        <div class="container p-4">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                <h4 class="mb-4 text-center fw-bold">QUALITY</h4>
                <select name="" id="to_value" class="p-2 rounded bg-light border-2 border-2 w-150px" required>
                    <option value="USD">USD</option>
                    <option value="INR">INR</option>
                    <option value="AED">AED</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="border rounded p-4 mx-auto bg-white">
                <form id="myForm" class="row g-4 mb-0">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <label class="mb-2">Hourly cost for Quality person</label>
                        <div class="h-33px d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                            <input type="text" id="hourlyCost" class="border rounded p-2 px-3 bg-light w-100"
                                name="hourlyCost" data-currentcurrency="USD" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <label class="mb-2">No of Machines</label>
                        <div class="h-33px d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                            <input type="text" id="machines" class="border rounded p-2 px-3 bg-light w-100"
                                name="machines" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <label class="mb-2">Machine running cost per hour</label>
                        <div class="h-33px d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                            <input type="text" id="machines_hourly_running_cost"
                                class="border rounded p-2 px-3 bg-light w-100" name="machines_hourly_running_cost"
                                required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <label class="mb-2">Documentation cost machine per year</label>
                        <div class="h-33px d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                            <input type="text" id="cost_machine" class="border rounded p-2 px-3 bg-light w-100"
                                name="cost_machine" data-currentcurrency="USD" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <label class="mb-2">Man Hours per day to copy data from paper forms into database</label>
                        <div class="h-33px d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                            <input type="text" id="hours_per_day" class="border rounded p-2 px-3 bg-light w-100"
                                name="hours_per_day" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pb-1">
                        <label class="mb-2">Number of New setups per month</label>
                        <div class="h-33px d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                            <input type="text" id="setups" class="border rounded p-2 px-3 bg-light w-100" name="setups"
                                data-currentcurrency="USD" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--                        
                        <div><input type="hidden" class="border rounded p-2 px-3 bg-light w-10" id="to_email"
                            name="to_email"></div> -->
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit"
                            class="px-5 py-2 rounded text-white border-0 text-decoration-none">Calculate</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>

        // var email = "<?php echo "$email" ?>"
        // document.getElementById("to_email").value = email

        // document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        //     convertCurrency();


        // });

        const apiKey = "Xi0wAt0uz97w1Am9aSLS6GUkfSKZG7tl";

        function change_hourly_cost() {

            const fromCurrency = document.getElementById("hourlyCost").dataset.currentcurrency;
            // alert(fromCurrency);
            const toCurrency = document.getElementById("to_value").value;
            // alert(toCurrency);
            const amount = document.getElementById("hourlyCost").value;

            const url = `https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?apikey=${apiKey}&from=${fromCurrency}&to=${toCurrency}&amount=${amount}`;

            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    const convertedAmount = data.result;
                    document.getElementById("hourlyCost").value = convertedAmount;

                    // Display the profit_unit in the div
                    // document.getElementById("profit_unit").textContent = `${convertedAmount} ${toCurrency}`;
                    document.getElementById("hourlyCost").setAttribute("data-currentcurrency", toCurrency);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }
        document.getElementById("to_value").addEventListener("input", change_hourlyCost);


        function change_machines_hourly_running_cost() {

            const fromCurrency = document.getElementById("machines_hourly_running_cost").dataset.currentcurrency;
            const toCurrency = document.getElementById("to_value").value;
            const amount = document.getElementById("machines_hourly_running_cost").value;

            const url = `https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?apikey=${apiKey}&from=${fromCurrency}&to=${toCurrency}&amount=${amount}`;

            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    const convertedAmount = data.result;
                    document.getElementById("machines_hourly_running_cost").value = convertedAmount;

                    // Display the profit_unit in the div
                    // document.getElementById("profit_unit").textContent = `${convertedAmount} ${toCurrency}`;
                    document.getElementById("machines_hourly_running_cost").setAttribute("data-currentcurrency", toCurrency);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }
        document.getElementById("to_value").addEventListener("input", change_machines_hourly_running_cost);


        function change_cost_machine() {

            const fromCurrency = document.getElementById("cost_machine").dataset.currentcurrency;
            const toCurrency = document.getElementById("to_value").value;
            const amount = document.getElementById("cost_machine").value;

            const url = `https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/convert?apikey=${apiKey}&from=${fromCurrency}&to=${toCurrency}&amount=${amount}`;

            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    const convertedAmount = data.result;
                    document.getElementById("cost_machine").value = convertedAmount;

                    // Display the profit_unit in the div
                    // document.getElementById("profit_unit").textContent = `${convertedAmount} ${toCurrency}`;
                    document.getElementById("cost_machine").setAttribute("data-currentcurrency", toCurrency);
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }
        document.getElementById("to_value").addEventListener("input", change_cost_machine);








        document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Capture the input values

            const hourlyCost = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hourlyCost').value);
            const machines = parseFloat(document.getElementById('machines').value);
            const machines_hourly_running_cost = parseFloat(document.getElementById('machines_hourly_running_cost').value);
            const cost_machine = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cost_machine').value);
            const hours_per_day = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hours_per_day').value);
            const setups = parseFloat(document.getElementById('setups').value);

            const selectedCurrency = document.getElementById('to_value').value;



            // Calculate the result

            const CostPerMachine = cost_machine * machines;
            const costSavedResponse = (((15 / 60) * hours_per_day * runningCost * hourlyCost) * 5) * 12;
            const costSavedManPower = hours_per_day * hourlyCost;
            const costSaved = CostPerMachine + costSavedResponse + costSavedManPower;

            let implementation;
            if (selectedCurrency === 'USD') {
                implementation = machines * 500 + machines * 100;
            } else if (selectedCurrency === 'INR') {
                implementation = machines * 83282.50 + machines * 8328.25;
            }
            else if (selectedCurrency === 'AED') {
                implementation = machines * 3673.00 + machines * 367.30;
            }

            const ROI = (implementation / costSaved) * 12;
            // const emailto = "<?php echo "$email" ?>"
            // console.log("email", emailto);



            // Store the result in localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('CostPerMachine', CostPerMachine);
            localStorage.setItem('costSavedResponse', costSavedResponse);
            localStorage.setItem('costSavedManPower', costSavedManPower);
            localStorage.setItem('costSaved', costSaved);
            localStorage.setItem('selectedCurrency', selectedCurrency);
            localStorage.setItem('implementation', implementation);
            localStorage.setItem('ROI', ROI);

            localStorage.setItem('hourlyCost', hourlyCost);
            localStorage.setItem('machines', machines);
            localStorage.setItem('machines_hourly_running_cost', machines_hourly_running_cost);
            localStorage.setItem('cost_machine', cost_machine);
            localStorage.setItem('hours_per_day', hours_per_day);
            localStorage.setItem('setups', setups);

            // Redirect to the second page
            window.location.href = `./form-2.php?costSaved=${costSaved}&ROI=${ROI}&hourlyCost=${hourlyCost}&machines=${machines}&machines_hourly_running_cost=${machines_hourly_running_cost}&cost_machine=${cost_machine}&hours_per_day=${hours_per_day}&setups=${setups}`;
        });
    </script>

    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!