# What is the difference between <button type="submit"> and <input type="submit"> in HTML

Tags: html

I am confused about  and  in HTML. Both these tags submit the form but is there any difference between them?

Comment: Inside a <button> element you can put text (and tags like <i>, <b>, <strong>, <br>, <img>, etc.). That is not possible with a button created with the <input> element

Comment: Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543615/difference-between-input-type-submit-and-button-type-submittext-butto