# Changes made to HTML output (ASP.Net) using JavaScript immediately undone

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have a page on which a list of properties is displayed (i.e houses). This list is made up using CSS. So I've built a second CSS class, which makes the properties/houses align properly in 2 columns. Until now I did this by pressing a button, posting back, and outputting different html (basicly the same, but with other Css class references).

Now I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript) on SO and I implemented a basic scenario. A div with the class "yellow" is written to the html page, and a button changes this class to "red". This happens, but the div immediately changes back to class "yellow".

I'm a very very beginner in JS but not a beginning programmer. This would be a great addition to my site, but I can't find a proper answer. I apologize if this question is redundant.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeView() {
        document.getElementById("box").className = " red";
    }
```

Grtz, thanks in advance, Christophe,

Comment: Are you sure the button doesn't also cause a postback?

Comment: Omg, that was actually it! I had a basic page with nothing else on it for testing purposes, and I didn't realise that that was actually a postback. I fixed it now. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a button element is of type 'submit' - which will cause your browser to post back to the server.

Try changing the type to button instead.

```
<input type="button" ....
```

More info on the difference here... [Difference between <input type='button' /> and <input type='submit' />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

Comment: Botch answers are correct, but yours is a bit more complete so I'll mark that one as the answer. Sorry for the not-so-needed question again.

Answer (score 1):

If your button causes a postback (possibly a server control with an `asp:` tag), the javascript changes you made will be lost as by default an asp button submits a page to the server as a result of which your page reloads.

If all you need to change the class of a `div` make it a simple html button like

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeView()" value="Change" />
```