# Html.BeginForm Post going to HttpGet action rather than HttpPost in IE, fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following in my Razor view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="grid_1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="ValSummary"> @Html.ValidationSummary(false)</div>


    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Role, MVC.Shared.Views.EditorTemplates.KeyValuePairSelectList, new { SelectListOptions = Model.RoleSelectList })<br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Trust, MVC.Shared.Views.EditorTemplates.KeyValuePairSelectList, new { SelectListOptions = Model.TrustSelectList.OrderBy(x => x.Text) })<br /><br />
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.GmcCode)<br /><br />


    <div class="createbutton">
        <input id="btnGoBack" type="button" value="Back"/>  
        <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
    </div>

}
```

In my controller I have

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(ViewModel viewModel)
{
}
```

In Firefox and Chrome everything works fine but in IE when the form is submitted the HttpGet action is being fired rather than the HttpPost.

There are no clues in the call stack or from the IE developer tools console.

Anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Could you post rendered html for the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Submit button should a real [submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON) with `type="Submit"`

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

to submit the form correctly in all browsers.

See this SO questions for further differences: [Difference between <input type='button' /> and <input type='submit' />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

Comment: @DeclanMcNulty strange it should work... are there any JavaScript involved in the form submission? Can you post the rendered html?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @nemesv, you are right about thejavascript. I had a click event on the submit button that was conditionally submitting the form based on some other criteria on the page. This was using $('form') to select the form and IE was intepreting this as the whole form rather than the one in my code above. I have refactored my code to give the form an ID and use a proer submit button