# Passing a long string from controller to view results in a long url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working with an ASP.NET MVC Web Application.I need to pass a long string from controller to view.The long string is saved in database as a Html encoded string and a Html decoded string has to be sent to the view in a textarea field:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Article(int id,string txt)
    {
        if (txt != "")
        {
            ArtModel am = new ArtModel();
            am.arttext = txt; //txt is the long string
            return View(am);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_Article", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
                                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input name="button" value="Update" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" class="submit" />
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.arttext)
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'arttext' );
</script>
}
```

I am using '_Article' action to fetch from database and this action redirects to 'Article' action with the parameter 'txt'.

When I click the button, it fetches the string from database(I haven't pasted the code) and saves it in the string 'txt' and is sent to the view.

There is no issue when the string length is small, the Html decoded string appears in the textarea. But if the string length is large, I get some errors stating that the url is too long or the query string is too long:

> Request URL Too Long
>   HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.

OR

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
>   The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

Can I pass the string using the same method(as I think it is a simple method) by tackling these errors?

Can I shorten the url in any way so that the long url error doesn't show up?

Please let me know if there's a different solution.

Thank You!

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code, but the error leads me to believe your form is GET, not POST. Please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: Why do you want to pass this in the URL?  What's passing the data to this view?  Can you use `TempData`?  Can you use a `POST` form?

Comment: Is the error happening before entering the Article method, or when returning the view? Is your form using GET or POST to submit the data?

Comment: I am using FormMethod.Post to submit the data.
Please refer my edit.

Comment: I tried to use TempData, but its not showing up in the textarea even for short strings.
@{var text = TempData["articletext"];}
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.arttext, htmlAttributes: new { Value = text })

Comment: I am suggesting that you don't accept this value in a URL, but find some other way of having it passed to your action method.  Passing long data in a URL is a bad idea.

Comment: Actually I realised that the string is appended in the url only after I got the error using the method mentioned in the question. I also used TempData but that too didn't work. Is there any method to pass the string which won't append anything to the url?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use POST as the method in your `@Html.BeginForm` statement.

Also, the `value="update"` might need to be `value="submit"` according to this question: [Html.BeginForm Post going to HttpGet action rather than HttpPost in IE, fine in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966345)

Increasing the maximum URL length will only delay the time before your next headache, unless you artificially limit the text length to the maximum allowed.