# Will a input type="submit" always be rendered as Button in browser?

Tags: asp.net, html

I saw the following snippet in a page generated by ASP.NET.

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$Button1" id="MainContent_Button1" type="submit" value="Button">
```

Question is,

Will the **type="submit"** control always be rendered as a **button** in browser?

This has direct impact on how the Coded UI test code should be write, if it is a Button, **HtmlInputButton** should be used, if not, we need to use other type to represent the input element.

Comment: The value is what you've provided as `Text`, hence the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I update my question, it should make more sense now.

Comment: by default, yes a submit type input is always rendered as a button. you can use css to override this though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between <input type='button' /> and <input type='submit' />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems like a content vs. styling confusion.

The `submit` type of the input just tells the rendering client that this particular input element should post the form it is contained in when triggered (e.g. via a mouse click).

Anyhow the current browsers got default style sheets included that style/render those inputs as buttons. But a default style isn't really necessary and thus could also be left out in a self-made HTML/CSS client.

Example: Webkit default styles for buttons:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
    -webkit-appearance: push-button;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    white-space: pre;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px outset buttonface;
    border-image: initial;
    color: buttontext;
    background-color: buttonface;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: If the rendering is override-able by a customer CSS, it basically could be rendered into any html tag, right?

Comment: @smwikipedia Yes, one could style any element as button. Normally, to have the browsers default button styling for an element, it's enough to set the `appearance: push-button;` (with correct vendor prefixes).

Answer (score 1):

No. A browser may display elements in different ways, or it may display nothing (if it is an aural browser, for example). Graphic browsers generally display `input type="button"` as a button, but this can be changed with CSS, or with JavaScript (which may change the `type` property). And the visual appearance of a button may vary a lot; there is no strict definition of what constitutes a button in the visual sense.