# Jquery post() to send message from form throw php

Tags: php, jquery, post

I'm using jquery to validate a form and then php to send the email with all the form content.

HTML - contact.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="message_validator.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form_contacto" charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="textbox" name="name" maxlength="12" />
  <input type="text" id="last_name" class="textbox" name="last_name" maxlength="12" />
  <input type="text" id="email" class="textbox" name="email" maxlength="40" />
  <input type="text" id="title" class="textbox_2" name="title" maxlength="40" />
  <textarea id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
  <input type="text" id="about" class="textbox_3" name="about" maxlength="40" />
  <input type="text" id="validation" class="textbox_4" name="validation" maxlength="40" />
  <input type="submit"  class="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JQUERY - message_validator.js

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        if($('.error_display').css("height")!="0"){
            $('.error_display').empty();
        }
        var errorlist = [];
        errorlist.length = 0;
        var email_check = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i;
        var name = $('input#name').val();
        var email = $('input#email').val();
        var message = $('textarea#message').val();
        var validation = $('input#validation').val();

        if(name == '' && email == '' && message == ''){
            errorlist.push("- ERROR ALL");
        }else{
            if (name == '') {
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }else if(name.length <= 2){
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }
            if (email == ''){
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }else if(!email_check.test(email)){
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }
            if (message == '') {
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }else if(message.length <= 5){
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }
            if (validation == '') {
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }else if(validation != 8){
                errorlist.push("-ERROR");
            }
        }

         if(errorlist.length >= 1){
            $('.error_display').animate({'height':errorlist.length*22}, {queue:false, duration:500});
            for(var i = 0; i < errorlist.length; i++) {
                $('.error_display').append(errorlist[i]+"<br/>");
                //errorlist[i].text.appendTo($('.error_display'));
                //$('.error_display').append(errorlist[i].val());
            } 
         }else{
            $("form#form_contacto").submit();
            $('.error_display').animate({'height':0}, {queue:false, duration:500});
            $('.success_display').animate({'height':75}, {queue:false, duration:500});
            $('#form_contacto').animate({'opacity':0.25}, {queue:false, duration:500});
            $('.submit').attr("disabled", true);
         }
    });
});
```

PHP - message_handler.php

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $about = $_POST['about'];
  $validation = $_POST['validation'];


  $email_from = 'example@example.com';
      $email_subject = "New Message";
      $email_body = "Received a new message from $name $last_name"."Visitor email: $visitor_email\n\n\n"."Title: $title\n"."Message sent:\n $message\n\n";


      $to = "example@example.com";

      $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

      $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

      mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
?>
```

The message is sent normally if I change the button to submit and put method="post" action="message_handler.php" in the form tag. But when I use that method it goes to the page message_handler.php and display a blank page and I want it only to send if the validation comes true from the message_validator.js so thats why I'm trying to use jquery to use the post() method.

I already tried in the last else the following:

```
else{
$("form#form_contacto").submit();

}
```

and

```
else{
$.post("message_handler.php", {name:name, email:email, last_name:last_name, title:title, message:message}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**message_handler.php**

***WARNING: You should protect this page from spam.  In its current state, you are extremely vulnerable***

change your call to the mail function to this

```
  if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) {
    echo "success";
  }
  else {
    echo "fail";
  }
```

**message_validator.js**

Add this to your else block

```
$.post(
    "message_handler.php",
    {
        name:name,
        email:email,
        last_name:last_name,
        title:title,
        message:message
    },
    function(result){
        // log to console for debug 
        console.log(result);
        if(result == 'success') {
            // do something here
        }
        else {
            // do something on failure
        }

});
```

**contact.php**

Change the type of the submit to button to [prevent form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

`<input type="button"  class="submit" value="Send">`

Comment: Thank you, but I think php is not sending back the result. I follow all your modifications but still not receiving any email in my gmail account throw the server where my site is hosted.

Comment: are you getting 'success' returned from the ajax post call?

Comment: hit f12, then click console.  Click the submit button on your page, and look for the response in the console.

Comment: I receive this message when i click the button submit:

Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.9.0.min.js:4

o jquery-1.9.0.min.js:4

j jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2

j jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2

j jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2
st.param jquery-1.9.0.min.js:4

st.extend.ajax jquery-1.9.0.min.js:4
st.(anonymous function) jquery-1.9.0.min.js:4
(anonymous function) message_validator.js:52
st.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.0.min.js:3
y.handle

Comment: can you post a link to the site?

Comment: add this     -- var last_name = $('input#last_name').val(); --
after -- var message = $('textarea#message').val(); --

Comment: just added. I am receiving multiple errors like "Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:236
chromeHidden.Port.dispatchOnDisconnect" in all input

Comment: add this -- var title= $('input#title').val(); -- after -- var message = $('textarea#message').val(); --

Comment: Please see the warning added to the answer.

Comment: What methods are best to secure the page?

Comment: Other issue I came across is that when the form submits an email I receive it two times

Comment: Your click event is firing twice.. Quick and dirty fix: add -- $('.submit').unbind('click'); -- above -- $('.submit').click(function(){ --  look at the source of your page.. you are rendering the page twice and "message_validator.js" is loading twice

Comment: How can I protect the page from spam besides using validation?

Comment: CAPTCHA, ip ban if submitted more than 3 times in one hour, http://akismet.com/, or search this website for the answer

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help was precious