# input type submit vs input type button

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have been trying to solve an annoying behavior with PHP (I think..). Maybe some of you have encountered the same and have some ideas. I have an html form and I use an  element with the onClick event that calls a javascript function. Once the script's content has been processed, I execute the form.submit() directive. It basically checks common things like length of fields, etc.

Now my problem is, when I use input type button, I set its name to submit1, and just to run a small test, I set the `<form id="register" action="<?php echo($PHP_SELF) ?>" method="post">`

I then put:

```
        <?php

if (isset($_POST["submit1"])) {
    echo "Submit button was pressed";
    die();

}

?>
```

However, I never see the message even though my input button's name is submit1. I then changed the input type to submit, and I click submit, I'll see the message but the only problem is that even if my javascript function finds any errors in the form, after clicking okay on the alert box, the form continues regardless. It only does this on submit type=submit.

If anyone is interested,

my buttons:
1st try:

```
<input type="button" name="submit1" class="submit" value="Register"      
onclick="validateFields()"  />
```

2nd try:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" class="submit" value="Create Account!"     
onclick="validateFields()"  />
```

Comment: @Sergio lol yes, that's not the problem.

Comment: Good, that was clear after you posted the rest of the code.

Comment: Do you have a `.preventDefault` inside the function `validateFields()` ?

Comment: `but the only problem is that even if my javascript function finds any errors in the form, after clicking okay on the alert box, the form continues regardless.` that is __javascript__ problem, not server side.

Comment: @Sergio the question doesn't have a `jquery` tag. use `return false`

Comment: Any solution? Client side just validates the length of fields and such, I just wanted to test out the server side and then I realized this problem. I can use input type submit, but then my validateFields() will not stop the form from executing, it'll execute either way (error or no errors)

Comment: post your __JAVASCRIPT__ code, server side codes are irrelevant here.

Comment: @itachi preventDefault is not jQuery - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Comment: @Sergio not sure it comes native in other browsers.

Comment: @itachi, true, old IE doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

To submit your form, the input field must be of the type `submit`, not `button`.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" class="submit" value="Create Account!"     
onclick="validateFields()"  />
```

You can also do:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit1" class="submit" onclick="validateFields()">
Create Account! </button>
```

And, to avoid your form from being submitted if there are errors, you can return false:

```
function validateFields() {
    //do validation
    if(failed) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah beat me to it. Your answer would be better by mentioning `preventDefault()` and `return;`

Answer (score 1):

For the `java script` problem may be you haven't put `return false` that's why form is submitting in any way.

```
if(a.value == ""){
alert("Name is empty");
return false; // this will prevent your form to be submit if condition fails
}
```

Whereas the difference between `button` and `submit` is that the `submit` is submitting the form(`posting form`) so `PHP` is eligible to get via `$_POST` but in `button` case the form isn't submitting so you cant get the values on other page rather than using `Ajax`.

[Similar Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I fixed it :).

I changed the input type into button, and changed my onclick="function(); return false"

And in my original JS code, I added: document.getElementById('myFormId').submit();

Now my JS code runs and it doesn't submit it until all the errors are fixed. Thank you. Silly mistake on my part.