# Can't redirect to a page after radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I have the following HTML to give two radio button options. If the user selects one option and click submit, it will go to the corresponding page.

```
<script src="js/jump.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="jump()">
<input type="radio" name="querytype" value="apple">Go to Apple page<br>
<input type="radio" name="querytype" value="orange">Go to Orange page<br>
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

In the JS file jump.js, I have the following function:

```
function jump() {
    var selected = document.getElementsByName('querytype');

    for(var i=0; i<selected.length; i++) {
    var value = selected[i].value;
    if (selected[i].checked) {
        if (value === 'apple') {
        window.location.href = '/myapp/apple-page';
        } else {
        window.location.href = '/myapp/orange-page';
        }
    } 
    }
}
```

But this is not working. When I make a choice and submit it, it doesn't go to either "Apple" or "Orange" page, but it shows a blank page. How do I make it happen?

Comment: Are you sure the function is running? Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: I debugged using Firebug and I'm sure the function is properly loaded after the HTML page is loaded. The interesting thing is: In the Firebug debug mode, if I put a breakpoint in jump(), I can get the page redirected for a short moment. But in normal mode, it doesn't work. Also, in Chrome browser debugger, even in debug mode, it doesn't redirect to the page. Very weird.

Comment: From your comment in the deleted answer, I suspect the issue is with a rewrite rule on server.

Comment: What do mean by "rewrite rule" on the server?

Comment: I think the webserver is translating `/myapp/apple-page` into `/myapp?querytype=apple`. Rewrite rules are in the .htaccess file. http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: So do I need to write some server-side code to respond the "submit" request? In that case, do I need to add something like `action="xxx" method="post"` in `<form>` element to handle the request? The current code is purely client-side.

Comment: If I'm guessing right, you need to remove the code that's doing this rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, I understand that you only want to redirect to Page X or Y according to user choice.
If this is the case then you have to change the "Submit" button type to "Button"
like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="jump()" value="ok">
```

and remove the attribute onsubmit="jump()" from the form tag.

Comment: sweet! This works finally. What's the difference between `type="button"` and `type="submit"` for radio button? And why my original code using `onsbumit` doesn't redirect?

Comment: @tonga - somebody has already asked this before, please look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit

Comment: Thanks. I understand that `button` doesn't submit unless it is associated with some JavaScript functions. But I still don't understand why `type="submit"` doesn't work in my case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put `return false` at the end of `jump()` to prevent the default form submission action.