# can't submit a form while clicking submit button in EJS

Tags: javascript, forms, node.js, express, ejs

Hi guys i ran into a problem that i don't understand why, it is very strange or maybe i write the code wrongly so i hope you guys can point out the mistake or enlighten me .

so i was trying to submit a form to my database and before submit the form the validate function will validate the data, if there's an error it will notify the user

when i click submit button the form cannot be submitted and nothing happened, no error in terminal , no error on console , nothing ( it looks like you click on  `<button>` inside a form, while the form is expecting `<input type="submit">` to submit the form>

here's the full code https://github.com/johnlim5847/form-test

**App.js** ( i think nothing wrong in here)

```
  var express = require('express'),
         app = express(),
       http = require('http'),
       path = require('path'),
       MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
       routes = require('./routes'),
       passport = require('passport');
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
        "use strict";
        if(err) throw err;
    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: 'Super Duper Awesome Duck' }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(app.router);
    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

    routes(app, db);

    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
      console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });

    });
```

**routes/index.js**

```
var SessionHandler = require('./session');

module.exports = exports = function(app, db) {
var sessionHandler = new SessionHandler(db);
app.use(sessionHandler.isLoggedInMiddleware);
// Signup form
app.post('/register', sessionHandler.handleSignup);

app.use(function (req,res) {
 res.status(404).render('error', {
 url: req.originalUrl
  });
});

app.get('*',function(req, res){
  res.render('master', { title: 'form' });
});


}
```

**routes/session.js**

```
var UsersDAO = require('../users').UsersDAO
  , SessionsDAO = require('../sessions').SessionsDAO;

/* The SessionHandler must be constructed with a connected db */
function SessionHandler (db) {
    "use strict";

    var users = new UsersDAO(db);
    var sessions = new SessionsDAO(db);



   function validateSignup(publicUsername, password, confirmPassword, email, confirmEmail, errors) {
        "use strict";
        var USER_RE = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,25}$/;
        var PASS_RE = /^.{6,100}$/;
        var EMAIL_RE = /^[\S]+@[\S]+\.[\S]+$/;

        errors['publicUsername_error'] = "";
        errors['password_error'] = "";
        errors['confirmPassword_error'] = "";
        errors['email_error'] = "";
        errors['confirmEmail_error'] = "";

        if (!USER_RE.test(publicUsername)) {
            errors['publicUsername_error'] = "Try just letters and numbers, e.g: Ed, 69, Kelvin and etc";
            return false;
        }
        if (!PASS_RE.test(password)) {
            errors['password_error'] = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
            return false;
        }
        if (password != confirmPassword) {
            errors['confirmPassword_error'] = "Password must match";
            return false;
        }
        if (!EMAIL_RE.test(email)) {
                errors['email_error'] = "Invalid email address";
                return false;
            }
         if (email != confirmEmail) {
            errors['confirmEmail_error'] = "Email must match";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    this.handleSignup = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";

        var email = req.body.email,
         confirmEmail = req.body.confirmEmail,
         password = req.body.password,
         confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword,
         firstName = req.body.firstName,
         lastName = req.body.lastName,
         penName = req.body.penName,
         publicUsername = req.body.publicUsername;

        // set these up in case we have an error case
        var errors = {'email': email,'publicUsername': publicUsername,'firstName': firstName,'lastName': lastName,'penName': penName}
        if (validateSignup(publicUsername, password, confirmPassword, email, confirmEmail, errors)) {
            users.addUser(email, password, firstName, lastName, penName, publicUsername, function(err, user) {
                "use strict";

                if (err) {
                    // this was a duplicate
                    if (err.code == '11000') {
                        errors['email_error'] = "Email already in use. Please choose another";
                        return res.render("register", errors);
                    }
                    // this was a different error
                    else {
                        return next(err);
                    }
                }

                sessions.startSession(user['_id'], function(err, session_id) {
                    "use strict";

                    if (err) return next(err);

                    res.cookie('session', session_id);
                    return res.redirect('/');
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log("user did not validate");
            return res.render("register", errors);
        }
    }
}
```

**register.ejs**

```
<div class="pure-u-1 text-center">
<form method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
    <fieldset>
    <legend><h1 class="pure-splash-subhead midnightblue"><span class='lightblue'>Join</span> us today and start write things that <span class='maroon'>matter</span></h1>
    </legend>
        <p class="text-center red">{{email_error}}</p>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input required name="email" class="pure-u-1-3" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
        <p class="text-center red">{{confirmEmail_error}}</p>
            <label for="confirmEmail">Confirm Email Address</label>
            <input required name="confirmEmail" class="pure-u-1-3" type="email" placeholder="Confirm Email Address">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
        <p class="text-center red">{{password_error}}</p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input required name="password" class="pure-u-1-3" type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
        <p class="text-center red">{{confirmPassword_error}}</p>
            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input required name="confirmPassword" class="pure-u-1-3" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
             <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input required name="firstName" class="pure-u-1-3" type="text" placeholder="Your first name">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input required name="lastName" class="pure-u-1-3" type="text" placeholder="and your last name">
        </div>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="penName"><abbr title="A pen name, nom de plume, or literary double, is a pseudonym adopted by an author. The author's real name may be known to only the publisher, or may come to be common knowledge.">Nom de plume</abbr></label>
            <input required name="penName" class="pure-u-1-3" type="text" placeholder="Pen Name eg:J.R.R. Tolkien">
        </div>

        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label for="publicUsername">Public Username</label>
            <input required name="publicUsername" class="pure-u-1-3" type="text">
            <p class="text-center red">{{publicUsername_error}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-u-1 ">
            <label for="conAndTerm" class="pure-checkbox">
                <input id="conAndTerm" type="checkbox"> I've read the <a class='link blue'href="#">terms and conditions</a>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <input type='submit'class="pure-button pure-button-secondary pure-u-1-3" value="Register">
            <br/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

i think it might be a silly mistake i hope there's nothing wrong with my HTML tag LOL

Comment: You can submit the form from a button via click handler, by finding the form and calling the submit() method of the form object.  This isn't an EJS thing, more just a straight up HTML thing. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit

Comment: nonono i was giving an explanation on how it feels when i click on the button

Comment: Make sure you have an action="/register" in your form.

Comment: My apologies; I misread your initial post completely.  Hector is likely correct, with no action defined the form won't go anywhere.

Comment: @HectorCorrea i can submit the form without the action="/register", of course it was before having the problem

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: when i click submit, nothing is change

Comment: john lim, try to do this - app.get('/register', sessionHandler.handleSignupView); app.post('/register', sessionHandler.handleSignup);

Answer (score 1):

ok, so after short debugging session:

taken from Angular's [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform)

> Since the role of forms in client-side Angular applications is
>   different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the
>   browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload
>   that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic
>   should be triggered to handle the form submission in an
>   application-specific way.
>
> For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission
>   to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute
>   specified.

so it seems like you did not provide proper handling for form submit :-)

so either provide one or add the 'action' attribute to the form - that should "fix" it

let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: but it works perfectly fine before this problem occurred.even without action attribute

Comment: please define _"before"_

Answer (score -1):

> You're missing the **action** attribute inside your **form** tag in *register.ejs*

It should be as following

```html
<form method="post" action="/user/register" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned">
```

Now upon hitting *"submit"* a **POST** request will be generated and server shall look for a **post** type of route mentioned in *action*.

---

> Another thing that's wrong with your code is ... you need to declare *SessionHandler* function using *"exports"* keyword as mentioned below.

```js
exports.SessionHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
  // Session handler with arrow function
}
```

> OR

```js
exports.SessionHandler = async function (req, res, next) {
  // Session handler without arrow function 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe you need a space so that `type='submit'class` becomes: `type='submit' class`.

Comment: thanks for the answering my question, but it still remain the same