# Java Script Console issue in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I get a problem with `JavaScript Console`. I did a login form example. In this example when ever clicks a  login button it goes to corresponding events in the JS. Here  the problem is i write some console logs in JS, In this console logs are shows when ever clicks login button then immediately hiding means just come and with in fraction of seconds its hiding.So I didn't have any idea so please see the below code and suggest me.

HTML Code :

```
<template name="login">
  <form id="login-form" action="action">
         <div>
              <h2> Login<h2>
              <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" /><br>
              <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" /><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login" />
          </div>
    </form>
</template>
```

JS Code :

```
 Template.login.events
  ({
    'submit #login-form' : function ()
    {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit) question. You can solve the issue by using `e.preventDefault()` in your event handler:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
 Template.login.events
  ({
    'submit #login-form' : function (e, t)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}
```

Or by using `<input type='button' value="Login" id="login" />` and registering the event handler so that it matches `click` events (not `submit`).

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you submit a form it makes another HTTP request which will reload the page and halt whatever meteor was doing. To prevent this, you can do something like:

```
Template.login.events({
  submit: function() {
    console.log('SUBMIT!');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Returning `false` from a handler is the same as calling both `stopImmediatePropagation` and `preventDefault` on the event.

Note that `events` will always be isolated to the template so you can just use `submit` instead of `submit #id` unless you have more that one form in the template.