# Two Submit button either In New Tab or at Self using JQuery Library

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a FORM with two submit button. What I wanted to happen is when the first button is clicked, it will submit on the tab itself. If the second button is clicked, it will proceed to a new tab.

HTML :

```
<form id="frm" action="" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="text" value="data" name="data">
    <input type="submit" name="first" id="first" value="Self"/>
    <input type="submit" name="second" id="second" value="Tab"/>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
$('form#frm').submit(function(){
    var open_new_tab = false;

    if($('#second').click){
        open_new_tab = true;
    }

    if ( open_new_tab ) {
        alert('opening to new tab');
        $('form#frm').attr('target', '_blank');
    }
    else{
        alert('opening to self_page');
        $('form#frm').attr('target', '_self');
    }
});
```

Please check this fiddle:
[Two Submit button in One Form](http://jsfiddle.net/J7T3j/2/)

**Note**: I wanted to pass on some data inside the FORM into the new tab or in the tab itself.

Comment: Made you shouldn't be using submit buttons but <a href> elements then there is no need for any JavaScript as this element has all the features you want inbuilt.

Comment: Or use buttons instead of submits, each with its own on click

Comment: @jeff - Don't wanna use <a href> because I need to pass on some data which I can't pass on. <a href='link.php?data=$data'> It's more complex.

Comment: @ElefantPhace - Button don't submit a form. See reference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit

Comment: I know what buttons do. You would have to make it submit yourself. Smart one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there, first you need to make `open_new_tab` available in the global scope by defining it **outside** your event handlers, then redefine the variable on the click event of either button. Then you can check for the value during your submit handler:

```
var open_new_tab = false; // variable now available in global scope

$('#second').click(function(){
    open_new_tab = true;
});

$('#first').click(function() {
    open_new_tab = false;
});

$('form#frm').submit(function(){    
    if (open_new_tab) {
        alert('opening to new tab');
        $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    } else{
        alert('opening to self_page');
        $(this).attr('target', '_self');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7T3j/4/)

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day. Will marked your answer right.