# How do i put the element in same line if i put it outside a form

Tags: html, css, forms

I want the register button to be in same line as login but it wont work when it is placed outside of the form.

```
<div style="float:right;min-width:440px;width:30%;padding-top:30px;">
<form>
Username:<input name="username" type="text" name="username" style="min-width:120px;"></input>
Password:<input name="password" type="text" name="password" style="min-width:120px;"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>
<button>Register</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try setting it position absolute and place it

Comment: I dont understand one thing. Why do you want to keep the register button outside? You can keep it within form without any issue.

Comment: Just `inline`d your form: http://jsfiddle.net/006smtuo/

Answer (score 0):

Deried from Vitorino Fernandes' comment. Try following -

```
<div style="float:right;min-width:440px;width:30%;padding-top:30px;">
<form>
    Username:<input name="username" type="text" name="username" style="min-width:120px;"></input><br />
Password:<input name="password" type="text" name="password" style="min-width:120px;"></input>
    <br /> <input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>
    <button style="position:absolute; left:140px; top:80px">Register</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to put the button outside the form since you don't want to submit the form on clicking the Register button.

This can be achieved by keeping the register button inside the form - use this for the register button:

```
<input type="button" value="Register"></input>
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8evgmrhr/1/) JSFiddle. The form will submit on clicking the login button but it won't submit on clicking the register button.

Also see: [Difference between <input type='button' /> and <input type='submit' />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s45wg9cx/)

```html
<div style="float:right;min-width:565px;width:30%;padding-top:30px;">
<form style="float:left">
Username:<input name="username" type="text" name="username" style="min-width:120px;"></input>
Password:<input name="password" type="text" name="password" style="min-width:120px;"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Login"></input>
</form>
<button  style="float:left">Register</button>
</div>
```