# Form "required" attribute in form input field not causing anything to happen

Tags: html, google-apps-script, forms, required

I'm Andrew from Italy, 
I'm trying to adapt a script I've found on line. It's a script that creates an HTML form and uploads answers in a spreadsheet.

This is the tutorial from wich I've started:

**GS CODE:**

```
var dropBoxId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Drive ID of 'dropbox' folder
var logSheetId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Drive ID of log spreadsheet

function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(formObject) {
try {
// Create a file in Drive from the one provided in the form
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dropBoxId);
var blob = formObject.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.myName);

// Open the log and record the new file name, URL and name from form
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logSheetId);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl(), formObject.myName, formObject.email]);

// Return the new file Drive URL so it can be put in the web app output
return file.getUrl();
} catch (error) {
return error.toString();
}
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="insert your name"/>
  <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="mail ">
  <input name="myFile" type="file" />
  <input type="button" value="send"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .uploadFiles(this.parentNode)" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">All done</a>';
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
</script>

<style>
  input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

I want to make some field required.

I've tried with

```
<input type="text" name="myName" required>
```

but nothing happened.

What can I do? Is there an easy solution?

thanks!!
Andrea

EDIT
After some suggestions I've updated the HTML code:

**NEW HTML CODE:**

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .uploadFiles(this)">

  <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="insert your name" required />
  <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="on" placeholder="mail ">
  <input name="myFile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="send"/>

</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
    function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">All done</a>';
    }
    function onFailure(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
</script>

<style>
  input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

Now if I don't upload any files the required function works correctly and the spreadsheet is updated. If I attach a file when I click the button the page refresh and the link of the script change in this way:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/dev?myName=FirstName&email=mymail%40mail.com&myFile=File1.txt
```

I've added some Logger.log in the GS code in this way:

```
var dropBoxId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Drive ID of 'dropbox' folder
var logSheetId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Drive ID of log spreadsheet
function doGet(e) {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}
function uploadFiles(formObject) {
try {
// Create a file in Drive from the one provided in the form
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dropBoxId);
var blob = formObject.myFile;    
var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + formObject.myName);
  Logger.log('blob : ' + blob)
  Logger.log('myName : ' + formObject.myName)

// Open the log and record the new file name, URL and name from form
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(logSheetId);
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
sheet.appendRow([file.getName(), file.getUrl(), formObject.myName, formObject.email]);

// Return the new file Drive URL so it can be put in the web app output
return file.getUrl();
} catch (error) {
return error.toString();
}
}
```

This is the output if I don't upload any files:

```
[15-05-26 09:33:47:789 CEST] blob : FileUpload
[15-05-26 09:33:47:789 CEST] myName : myFirstName
```

If I attach a file the log is totally blank.

I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: If you want to improve your question, delete stuff like where you are from, or "thanks".  Including the code and what you tried is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are using does not have a "submit" type input (input tag displayed as a submit button).  The button in the form you are using is an input tag of the type "button".

```
<input type="button">
```

The `required` attribute will ***not*** work with an input type of "button".  It ***will*** work with an input tag of type "submit".

```
<input type="submit">
```

[StackOverflow - Difference between button and submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

But what exactly does "submit" do?  An input tag of the type "submit" causes whatever action is specified in the form tag to be executed or alternatively, causes the `onsubmit` to trigger:

```
<form action="urlToInvoke">
```

onsubmit:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
```

Your input form has no `action` or `onsubmit` attribute:

```
<form id="myForm">
```

In your form, the `google.script.run` function is called from input tag of the type "button".

Current set up:

```
  <input type="button" value="send"
  onclick="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .uploadFiles(this.parentNode)" />
```

If you want to try to get the `required` functionality to work, here's what you can try:

Change the input type to "submit":

```
<input type="submit">
```

Put the `google.script.run` code into an `onsubmit` attribute of the form:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .uploadFiles(this)">
```

Make sure that you change `this.parentNode` to `this`.  Using just the `this` keyword alone refers to whatever element it's being used in.  When the `onsubmit` was being executed from the button, the button is a child of the form.  In that case, it was necessary to get the parent, which is the form, to pass to the function, thus `this.parentNode`.

Comment: Wow! thanks! It  seems to work! Tomorrow I try to integrate this code with other parts... Thanks a lot!

I'm new here, have I to do something? Have to update my first post with the solution to be more useful for other users?

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct and delete your answer.  Don't put the answer in your question.

Comment: Hi, I've changed the code as you suggested. Now the required function seems to work properly but if I add a file nothing happens (neither in spreadsheet, neither in the folder). The page refresh (and the link change with the value of the form field), If I don't upload any file the spreadsheet is correctly updated. Do you know why?

Comment: You need to use some `Logger.log('my variable name: ' + variableName)` statements in the `.gs` code to check whether the file is getting passed in, and if it's a blob type.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my first post with new information and the explaination of the problem

Comment: I think that some people where having issues with file uploads using the IFRAME sandbox mode.  See this post in the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4610&can=5&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Comment: I've read the article, I've changed 'return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');' to 'return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);' but nothing changed. Do you think I have more to do?