# Spring ModelAttribute not biding values Tomcat 9, Spring 5 MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat9

I migrated from Spring 3 to 5, upgraded to Tomcat 9. After upgrading not able to get the values from JSP to Controller. @ModelAttribute is not binding the values entered in JSP, while submitting the form.

JSP Code:

```
<form:form action="/login" modelAttribute="identity" id="loginForm" cssClass="clearfix nodisplay">

<div class="grouping text">
    <label for="email">E-mail Address</label>
    <form:input path="email" id="email" cssClass="regInput" cssErrorClass="error" />
    <form:errors path="email" cssClass="errors" />
</div>
<div class="grouping text">
    <label for="pwd">Password</label>
    <form:password path="pwd" id="pwd" cssClass="regInput" cssErrorClass="error" autocomplete="off" />
    <form:errors path="pwd" cssClass="errors" />
</div>
<div class="grouping remember">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" />
    <label for="remember">Remember Me</label>
</div>
<div class="btns clearfix">
    <span class="login-btn">
        <input type="hidden" name="cookieExist" id="cookieExist" value="false" />
        <button type="button" name="login" class="btn js-login-btn"><span class="pictos">K</span> Login</button>
    </span>
    <span class="password-forget">
        <a href="/passwordreset">I forgot my password</a>
    </span>
</div>
</form:form>
```

Controller Code

```
 @Controller
 public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/login")
    public String loginGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap modelMap,
                        @ModelAttribute Identity identity){

        // commented business logic code
        return "login";
    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/login")
    public String loginPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            ModelMap modelMap, @ModelAttribute("identity") Identity identity, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        //commented out business logic
        return "dashboard";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("identity")
    public Identity formBackingObject() {
        return new Identity();
    }
}
```

I have migrated with no webxml way, not sure what else i'm missing here?

Comment: Any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736056/button-type-button-vs-submit

Comment: I use JS function to submit "form",  i tried both ways with `type="submit"` in button as well with `$(this).closest("form").submit();` either way problem exists!

Answer (score 0):

No need of action here in the `form` tag. Mention `method` in the `form` tag. So chnage to:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="identity" method="post" id="loginForm" cssClass="clearfix nodisplay">
```

And also change your primary action button to:

```
<input type="submit" ... />
```

Comment: @Pruthviraj Can you show the code where you put the command object in the model?