# Does type='button' even do anything?

Tags: html, dom

I just noticed this and am curious. I have two `<span>`s with onClick events that do basically the same thing; one had `type='button'`, but the other did not. They were both behaving exactly the same.

> Is there any point to adding `type='button'` to an element other than making it more clear what it is?

Even a standard `button` element seems to behave exactly the same with and without.

`<button  onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>`

&&

`<button type="button" onclick="alert('Hello world!')">Click Me!</button>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736056/button-type-button-vs-submit

Comment: a button without type=button inside a form will submit the whole form.

Comment: Outside of a form, is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a form to see the difference:

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('submited...')">
  <button>Click me</button>
</form>

<form onsubmit="alert('submited...')">
  <button type="button">Click me</button>
</form>
```

A `button` tag without `type` attribute in the first example, it relates to the *submit* button (`<button type="submit">Click me</button>`) while the second button doesn't.

Comment: Is there any difference outside of a form?