# .submit() function not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am facing on problem my submit function not working I don't know where is the problem. I am using laravel framework 5.2 h

```js
$('#CheckImageCount').on('click', function() {
  var arr = [];
  $('.table-error').find('tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td:eq(1)').find('select').val() != '') {
      if ($(this).find('td:eq(2)').find('select').val() == '') {
        arr.push('false');
      } else {
        arr.push('true');
      }
    } else {
      arr.push('true');
    }
  });
  if ($.inArray('false', arr) > -1) {
    swal("Alert!", "Please Select Working Hours in right way!")
    return false;
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'CheckImageCount',
      success: function(resp) {
        if ($.trim(resp) == "empty") {
          $('.error-1').fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
          return false;
        } else {
          $("#registerBusiness").submit(); // here i want to submit the form
        }
      },
      error: function() {}
    });
  }
});
```

My form id is **registerBusiness** it not submit the form even my page not
goto that function here is my form  and submit button

```
<form id="registerBusiness" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/business-for-sale' )}}">{{ csrf_field() }}
```

And Submit buttton

```
<button id="CheckImageCount" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Save And Continue </button>
```

Comment: If ANYTHING in the form is called "submit" it will fail. Do you have any console errors?

Comment: no i have no errors when i click on submit buton only ajax runs and my page not go to that action

Comment: You should use type="submit", not "button"
Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit

Comment: Try to put one log statement in ajax error implementation. Ajax might giving error

Comment: no i have to use button because i have use dropzone for multiple images when user click on submit button it submits the form and my ajax is not running on that time

Comment: you have to submit it manually by calling method submit, replace return true by $("#registerBusiness").submit() then it will work

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: did you try  jquery document.ready = (function () {})(); ??

Comment: yes @mehmet i have tried

Comment: @Artsiom he should not use type=submit if he wants to submit the form after performing ajax testing. If he uses a submit  button he needs to use the on("submit" and preventDefault

Comment: @NileshDaladra he does not need to use any return since it is type=button

Comment: Do you have more than one form on the page with the same ID?

Comment: no i have one form with one id only

Comment: @mplungjan you are right ...but button type should be type="submit" then it will work

Comment: @NileshDaladra that is incorrect