# PHP code is converted as comments in browser and $_REQUEST is not displaying any data?

Tags: php, request

I have created two simple web pages, one is written in HTML, and the second is written in PHP. In the HTML page, I include form tag with action attribute and its attribute value is index.php(second page) and index.php(second page) include $_REQUEST but no value is displayed.

html page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testing of php</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>here the value will be displayed</h3>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
please enter your name:
<input type="text" name="don"></input><br>
<input type="button" value="send"></input>
</form></body>
</html>
```

php page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testing of php</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

echo "hello:";
echo $_REQUEST['don'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is hello is printing?

Comment: I don't see $_REQUEST in the php code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <input type='button' /> and <input type='submit' />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

Answer (score 2):

The type should be `submit` not `button` to submit the form using post method :

```
<input type="submit" value="send"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make another input type.
Working code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testing of php</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>here the value will be displayed</h3>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
please enter your name:
<input type="text" name="don"></input><br>
<input type="submit" value="send"></input>
</form></body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testing of php</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

echo "hello:";
echo $_REQUEST['don'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Comment: your code has syntax error in line with "echo "hello":;"

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
return one of this values : 
'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT'.   so you dont need to check if the methos is  post or no