# How to solve javascript redirection problem?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to do client-side validation using javascript and all the things are working properly, only it doesn't redirect to another page -> **redirect.html**

After clicking on the alert pop-up it again loads the index.html.

```js
document.getElementById('sub-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var yearBirth = document.getElementById('dob').value;
var phoneNum = document.getElementById('ph-no').value;
var emailID = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var rePassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;

if (firstName.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the first name!');
}else if (lastName.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the last name!');
}else if (yearBirth.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter date of birth!');
}else if (phoneNum.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the phone number!');
}else if (phoneNum.length > 10) {
    alert('Check phone number!');
}else if (emailID.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the email ID !');
}else if (password.length === 0 && (rePassword.length === 0 || rePassword.length !== 0)) {
    alert('Enter the password!');
}else if (rePassword.length === 0) {
    alert('Re-enter the password!');
}else {
    alert('Redirecting to another page....');
    window.location = 'redirect.html';
}  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="form-box">
            <form class="input">
                <input class="input-field" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
                <input class="input-field" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
                <input class="input-field" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="date">
                <input class="input-field" id="ph-no" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text">
                <input class="input-field" id="email" placeholder="Email ID" type="email">
                <input class="input-field" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password">
                <input class="input-field" id="re-password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" type="password">
                <button class="btn" id="sub-btn" type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `type="submit"` to this: `type="button"`

Comment: No, leave it at `submit` and add `action="redirect.html" onsubmit="return yourvalidator()"`. There is no need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: why it will not work if I use type = "submit"? @GetSet

Comment: What should I write in place of  "yourvalidator()" if I use addActionListner? @JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring the link [button type submit/button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290215/difference-between-input-type-button-and-input-type-submit)

```js
document.getElementById('sub-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var yearBirth = document.getElementById('dob').value;
var phoneNum = document.getElementById('ph-no').value;
var emailID = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var rePassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;

if (firstName.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the first name!');
}else if (lastName.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the last name!');
}else if (yearBirth.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter date of birth!');
}else if (phoneNum.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the phone number!');
}else if (phoneNum.length > 10) {
    alert('Check phone number!');
}else if (emailID.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the email ID !');
}else if (password.length === 0 && (rePassword.length === 0 || rePassword.length !== 0)) {
    alert('Enter the password!');
}else if (rePassword.length === 0) {
    alert('Re-enter the password!');
}else {
    alert('Redirecting to another page....');
    window.location = 'redirect.html';
}  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="form-box">
            <form class="input">
                <input class="input-field" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
                <input class="input-field" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
                <input class="input-field" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="date">
                <input class="input-field" id="ph-no" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text">
                <input class="input-field" id="email" placeholder="Email ID" type="email">
                <input class="input-field" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password">
                <input class="input-field" id="re-password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" type="password">
                <button class="btn" id="sub-btn" type="button">SIGN UP</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add event preventdefault I think

Comment: I don't know what is event preventdefault. Can you explain a bit about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('sub-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault()
var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var yearBirth = document.getElementById('dob').value;
var phoneNum = document.getElementById('ph-no').value;
var emailID = document.getElementById('email').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
var rePassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;

if (firstName.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the first name!');
}else if (lastName.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the last name!');
}else if (yearBirth.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter date of birth!');
}else if (phoneNum.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the phone number!');
}else if (phoneNum.length > 10) {
    alert('Check phone number!');
}else if (emailID.length === 0) {
    alert('Enter the email ID !');
}else if (password.length === 0 && (rePassword.length === 0 || rePassword.length !== 0)) {
    alert('Enter the password!');
}else if (rePassword.length === 0) {
    alert('Re-enter the password!');
}else {
    alert('Redirecting to another page....');
    window.location = 'redirect.html';
}  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) already has a built in redirect functionality by using the attribute `action` which also provides the benefit of actually posting the data to the desired link, if required.

Furthermore `form` has an event `onsubmit` which gets executed before submitting the form and can be cancelled by returning `false`.

Since all the mentioned requirements for your code are already given by the default behaviour of `form`, there is less reason not to use it.

Here is what you would need to change:

- Instead of defining a click event, you define a standalone validation
  function (=`myValidator()`), which returns `true` once all criterias are fulfilled and
  `false` until. This better good practise anyway, since you can call it
  independent of click events.
- Setting the `action`of the `form` to the desired URL (=`redirect.html`)
- Forward the `return` of `myValidator()` to the `onsubmit` event on the `form`

```js
function myValidator(){
  //REM: returns true once valid, false until.
  var tReturn = true;

  var firstName = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById('lname').value;
  var yearBirth = document.getElementById('dob').value;
  var phoneNum = document.getElementById('ph-no').value;
  var emailID = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  var rePassword = document.getElementById('re-password').value;

  if (firstName.length === 0) {
      alert('Enter the first name!');
      tReturn = false
  }else if (lastName.length === 0) {
      alert('Enter the last name!');
      tReturn = false
  }else if (yearBirth.length === 0) {
      alert('Enter date of birth!');
      tReturn = false
  }else if (phoneNum.length === 0) {
      alert('Enter the phone number!');
      tReturn = false
  }else if (phoneNum.length > 10) {
      alert('Check phone number!');
      tReturn = false
  }else if (emailID.length === 0) {
      alert('Enter the email ID !');
      tReturn = false
  }else if (password.length === 0 && (rePassword.length === 0 || rePassword.length !== 0)) {
      alert('Enter the password!');
      tReturn = false
  }else if (rePassword.length === 0) {
      alert('Re-enter the password!');
      tReturn = false
  };

  return tReturn
}
```

```html
<!--REM: It is better practise to assign those events using javascript - I merely leave it here to point put the event/difference -->
<form class="input" action="redirect.html" onsubmit="return myValidator()">
    <input class="input-field" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
    <input class="input-field" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
    <input class="input-field" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="date">
    <input class="input-field" id="ph-no" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text">
    <input class="input-field" id="email" placeholder="Email ID" type="email">
    <input class="input-field" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password">
    <input class="input-field" id="re-password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" type="password">
    <button class="btn" id="sub-btn" type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```

Also note that empty inputs can nowadays be prevented by using the attribute [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) as well as other nice form-features and be styled accordingly using pseudo-css-classes.

```html
<form class="input" action="redirect.html">
    <input class="input-field" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required>
    <input class="input-field" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" required>
    <input class="input-field" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="date" required>
    <input class="input-field" id="ph-no" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text" required>
    <input class="input-field" id="email" placeholder="Email ID" type="email" required>
    <input class="input-field" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password" required>
    <input class="input-field" id="re-password" placeholder="Re-enter Password" type="password" required>
    <button class="btn" id="sub-btn" type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
</form>
```